# Python List all devices on local network, along with ip address

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, nmap

I'm trying to somehow get a list of all connected devices on a network, and then show their ip with it. I want it to show something like this:

```
computername - 192.168.0.0
computer2 - 192.168.100.43
```

I have tried nmap and after a long time I was able to use it but it wont work.

*I'm using Python 3.6.5, Windows 8.1.*

If anyone could answer, it would help a lot.

**Edit: I did go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207234) before, but I'm not sure how to list the names and ip using that method.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207234/list-of-ip-addresses-hostnames-from-local-network-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `arp -a` and scrape the results of `os.popen`:

```
import os, re
full_results = [re.findall('^[\w\?\.]+|(?<=\s)\([\d\.]+\)|(?<=at\s)[\w\:]+', i) for i in os.popen('arp -a')]
final_results = [dict(zip(['IP', 'LAN_IP', 'MAC_ADDRESS'], i)) for i in full_results]
final_results = [{**i, **{'LAN_IP':i['LAN_IP'][1:-1]}} for i in final_results]
```

Sample output:

```
[{'IP': '?', 'LAN_IP': '192.168.1.4', 'MAC_ADDRESS': '11:1a:ec:da:d4:ee'}, ...]
```

`arp -a` gives a full listing of all the devices on the network of the machine executing the command.

Comment: arp -a doesn't give the names of the computers though, it gives:
ip - physical - type 
I want it to show the name and ip. And that code doesn't work too (https://pastebin.com/THszrZfx)

Comment: `KeyError: 'LAN_IP'`