# How to Scan for IP cameras on local network using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, camera

I've seen demos with wireshark and 3rd party utilities, but i've yet to see any in python. I've seen [scapy](https://github.com/secdev/scapy) but I'm not an infosec guy so this domain is quite confusing.

Anyone know how I can use python to scan for networked IP cameras on home network?

Answer (score 0):

you might start with the [python bindings](https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/) for nmap or [scapy](https://scapy.net/). check this answer as well:
[List of IP addresses/hostnames from local network in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207234/list-of-ip-addresses-hostnames-from-local-network-in-python)