# How to get a list of all the computers connected to my home's wifi

Tags: python, ip

I use sockets to communicate with several computers. instead of typing manually the ip's of the selected computer, I want to get a list of all the computers's IP that connected to my home network. For exemple, I have 3 computers connected to my network, and i want to get a list of all those computers's ip.
IMPORTANT- if it wasn't clear, I want to write a method in python that do this (returnes the list).
THANKS! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of IP addresses/hostnames from local network in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207234/list-of-ip-addresses-hostnames-from-local-network-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use nmap module.
With its help you can scan the network, more info on https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/