# os.popen subprocess conversion

Tags: python, string, indexing, subprocess

This snippet gets me the dotted quad of my BSD network interface.
I would like to figure out how to use the subprocess module instead.

```
ifcfg_lines = os.popen("/sbin/ifconfig fxp0").readlines()
x = string.split(ifcfg_lines[3])[1]
```

Seems as if I can't use subprocess in exactly the same way.
I don't think I want shell=True or PIPE.
What should I do to make the output indexable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

ifcfg_lines = Popen("/sbin/ifconfig fxp0",shell=True,stdout=PIPE).stdout.readlines()
x = string.split(ifcfg_lines[3])[1]
```

For a little more elegance, hide the details:

```
def getBSDIP():
   from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
   import string

   CURRENT = Popen("/sbin/ifconfig fxp0", shell=True,stdout=PIPE).stdout.readlines()
   return(string.split(CURRENT[3])[1])
```

If you are going to use subprocess to do this then elegance is a bit limited because you are essentially doing something like screenscraping, except here you are scriptscraping. If you want a truly general solution, use the socket library, i.e. let Python handle the portability.

Often, when you look at a bit of code and you wish that there was a better cleaner way to do it, this means that you need to question your assumptions, and change the algorithm or architecture of the solution.

Comment: Uh. Yeah. I don't seem to have a PIPE module. Where the hell does PIPE come from?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html talks about "stdin=PIPE and stdout=PIPE must be specified."
So I do specify them and python doesn't know wtf I'm talking about :)

Comment: `from subprocess import Popen,PIPE`

Comment: Really? Why should I need to specify it? 

Rhetorical question. I know you are not Guido.

Comment: CURRENT = Popen("/sbin/ifconfig fxp0", shell=True,stdout=PIPE).stdout.readlines()

This works and x = string.split(CURRENT[3])[1] can now get the correct IP address. But is there a more elegant way?

Comment: you should use something like lines, errors = Popen(['/sbin/ifconfig', 'fxp0'],....).communicate(). Otherwise you can catch a sigpipe on a long program output and introduce incorrectly quoted arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like:

```
import socket
ipadr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

as in [Finding Local IP Addresses in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-in-python) and remove the subprocess dependency? There are also some other suggestions in that question.

I also found a post on the [netifaces](http://alastairs-place.net/netifaces/) package that does aims to do this with better cross-platform support.

Comment: Heh. I was using the socket module in a less elegant way but discovered that I was getting the wrong IP back because of DNS.
The server is a domestic broadband network client so DNS is going to be wrong unless my dyndns.org hostname is resolving correctly which it is not.

Comment: Fair enough, I wondered if that was why you were getting the ip by device name. How about the netifaces approach? It uses system calls instead of dns.

Comment: I had been doing this: 
CURRENT = socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), None)[0][4][0]
For whatever reason, the above (and your) syntax gets back 173.48.208.152 while /sbin/ifconfig fxp0 renders: 173.48.204.168 .

Comment: I am not familiar with netifaces.