# Python: get default gateway for a local interface/ip address in linux

Tags: python, linux, routes, networking

On Linux, how can I find the default gateway for a local ip address/interface using python?

I saw the question "How to get internal IP, external IP and default gateway for UPnP", but the accepted solution only shows how to get the local IP address for a network interface on windows.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use python to execute the system's 'route' command and then process the output to get the default gateway. There might also be a flag for route to print only that. I don't know a python way atm. Good luck.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For those people who don't want an extra dependency and don't like calling subprocesses, here's how you do it yourself by reading `/proc/net/route` directly:

```
import socket, struct

def get_default_gateway_linux():
    """Read the default gateway directly from /proc."""
    with open("/proc/net/route") as fh:
        for line in fh:
            fields = line.strip().split()
            if fields[1] != '00000000' or not int(fields[3], 16) & 2:
                # If not default route or not RTF_GATEWAY, skip it
                continue

            return socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L", int(fields[2], 16)))
```

I don't have a big-endian machine to test on, so I'm not sure whether the endianness is dependent on your processor architecture, but if it is, replace the `<` in `struct.pack('<L', ...` with `=` so the code will use the machine's native endianness.

Comment: This only works if you have one default gateway. If you have multiple it is the one with the lowest metric.

Answer (score 20):

For completeness (and to expand on alastair's answer), here is an example that uses "netifaces" (tested under Ubuntu 10.04, but this should be portable):

```
$ sudo easy_install netifaces
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Oct  1 2012, 22:04:36)
...
$ ipython
...
In [8]: import netifaces
In [9]: gws=netifaces.gateways()
In [10]: gws
Out[10]:
{2: [('192.168.0.254', 'eth0', True)],
 'default': {2: ('192.168.0.254', 'eth0')}}
In [11]: gws['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][0]
Out[11]: '192.168.0.254'
```

Documentation for 'netifaces':  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces/

Comment: On Debian/Ubuntu install by `apt-get install python3-netifaces` or `apt-get install python-netifaces` if you use Python 3 or Python 2, respectively.

Answer (score 6):

It seems http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynetinfo/0.1.9 can do this, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: That library is great!

It has a netinfo.get_routes method that returns a tuple of dictionaries containing precisely the data I needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of [`netifaces`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces) can do this too, but unlike `pynetinfo`, it will work on systems other than Linux (including Windows, OS X, FreeBSD and Solaris).

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_ip():
    file=os.popen("ifconfig | grep 'addr:'")
    data=file.read()
    file.close()
    bits=data.strip().split('\n')
    addresses=[]
    for bit in bits:
        if bit.strip().startswith("inet "):
            other_bits=bit.replace(':', ' ').strip().split(' ')
            for obit in other_bits:
                if (obit.count('.')==3):
                    if not obit.startswith("127."):
                        addresses.append(obit)
                    break
    return addresses
```

Answer (score 1):

for Mac:

```
import subprocess

def get_default_gateway():
    route_default_result = str(subprocess.check_output(["route", "get", "default"]))
    start = 'gateway: '
    end = '\\n'
    if 'gateway' in route_default_result:
        return (route_default_result.split(start))[1].split(end)[0]

print(get_default_gateway())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution if you have multiple default gateways.

```
import socket, struct
from pprint import pprint as pp

with open("/proc/net/route") as fh:
    # skip header
    next(fh)
    route_list = []
    for line in fh:
        routes = line.strip().split()
        destination = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L", int(routes[1], 16)))
        if destination != "0.0.0.0":
            continue
        gateway = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L", int(routes[2], 16)))
        mask = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L", int(routes[7], 16)))
        metric = routes[6]
        interface = routes[0]
        route_table = (destination, gateway, mask, metric, interface)
        route_list.append(route_table)
    pp(route_list)

#[('0.0.0.0', '0.0.0.0', '0.0.0.0', '0', 'wlan0'),
# ('0.0.0.0', '192.168.225.1', '0.0.0.0', '1024', 'usb0')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this (Tested with python 2.7 and Mac OS X Capitain but should work on GNU/Linux too):
import subprocess

```
def system_call(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen([command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    return p.stdout.read()


def get_gateway_address():
    return system_call("route -n get default | grep 'gateway' | awk '{print $2}'")

print get_gateway_address()
```

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04, replace the system call with `route | grep default | sed -r 's/\s+/ /g' | cut -f 2 -d ' '`.

Answer (score 0):

here my solution to get default gateway for Mac and Linux with python:

```
import subprocess
import re
import platform

def get_default_gateway_and_interface():
    if platform.system() == "Darwin":
        route_default_result = subprocess.check_output(["route", "get", "default"])
        gateway = re.search(r"\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}", route_default_result).group(0)
        default_interface = re.search(r"(?:interface:.)(.*)", route_default_result).group(1)

    elif platform.system() == "Linux":
        route_default_result = re.findall(r"([\w.][\w.]*'?\w?)", subprocess.check_output(["ip", "route"]))
        gateway = route_default_result[2]
        default_interface = route_default_result[4]

    if route_default_result:
        return(gateway, default_interface)
    else:
        print("(x) Could not read default routes.")

gateway, default_interface = get_default_gateway_and_interface()
print(gateway)
```