# How can I get the default gateway IP with Python?

Tags: python, ip

I want to get the IP of the default gateway (internal router IP) using Python. I'm really new to Python so not sure how this works.

I know you can get the IP of your machine with:

```
import socket
internal_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print internal_ip
```

So I'm thinking it must be something similar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761829/python-get-default-gateway-for-a-local-interface-ip-address-in-linux/2761952#2761952 this looks like a possible solution.

Comment: @Reiner Gerecke thanks for your reply, yeah that looks, but it's linux only. i'm working windows - plus i'd like to use something that is platform independent if possible. there's 'import subprocess subprocess.call('ipconfig /all')' in windows, which returns all the info, but i'm hoping to use the code on different platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, you should use [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) along with proper query to lookup properties of an object (e.g. network devices). The following Python code prints IPv4 and default gateway addresses on my Windows 7 machine:

**Code:**

```
import wmi

wmi_obj = wmi.WMI()
wmi_sql = "select IPAddress,DefaultIPGateway from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled=TRUE"
wmi_out = wmi_obj.query( wmi_sql )

for dev in wmi_out:
    print "IPv4Address:", dev.IPAddress[0], "DefaultIPGateway:", dev.DefaultIPGateway[0]
```

**Output:**

```
IPv4Address: 192.168.0.2 DefaultIPGateway: 192.168.0.1
```

You can find more details and tricks of performing WMI operations on network devices on [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315292.aspx).

For Linux, [PyNetInfo](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynetinfo) as suggested on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761829/python-get-default-gateway-for-a-local-interface-ip-address-in-linux/2761952) would be a good approach. Although on Linux you can get around having to depend on an additional module by reading [PROC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proc_filesystem) entries among other `import os; os.system(...)` tricks.

Comment: Worth adding that the latest version of the [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces/) module can read gateway information and should work on a variety of platforms.