# Getting eth0 gateway, SSID, PSK, Timezone in Raspberry Pi using Python

Tags: python, linux, networking, timezone, raspberry-pi

I am trying to work on a GUI application on Raspberry Pi in which there is a Settings section. Now, in this section, I want the users to be able to configure gateway, ssid, psk, and timezone for their needs. In order to make this possible, I am planning on replacing /etc/network/interfaces for gateway (and also IP, but that I did already). For SSID and PSK, I will replace the file /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf. Now I have two seperate questions and I will gladly appreciate any help:

1. How to get the current gateway (eth0), ssid, psk, and timezone
   on my device?
2. What can I do to replace the timezone on Raspberry Pi. In layman's
   terms,  I want to be able to change timezone like with the command
   'sudo raspi-config', but from Python.

I have searched a few examples of how to get the gateway but they didnt work. I'm hoping I can get some idea from you guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would this be of any help to the default route part?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761829/python-get-default-gateway-for-a-local-interface-ip-address-in-linux

Comment: Hello, that seems like it should help but could you please help me with the usage. I did 'pip install X.tar.gz' and it was successful. Now, when I call 'import pynetinfo' my app does not execute. What should I do ?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Apparently it is 'import netinfo'