# Find default gateway address for Windows and Linux on python

Tags: python, networking, gateway

I want to save my default gateway in a variable for future using, like printing it, or send a ping to it....
I want the code will work on Windows and Linux, so I worte this code:

```
import os
if os.name == "Linux":
    dgw = os.system('ip r | grep default | awk {"print $3"}')
    print dgw
if os.name == "Windows":
    dgw = os.system('ifconfig | findstr /i "Gateway"')
    print dgw
```

But the dgw variable is not saving my default gateway...

python 2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: get default gateway for a local interface/ip address in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761829/python-get-default-gateway-for-a-local-interface-ip-address-in-linux)

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, `os.name` for Windows is `'nt'`, and Linux it is `'posix'`.

This is also highlighted in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.name):

> The name of the operating system dependent module imported. The following names have currently been registered: 'posix', 'nt', 'java'.

If you want to target more specific platforms, using [`sys.platform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform) is the better option.

Secondly, using the [`netifaces`](https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/) module works well for Windows and Linux:

```
import netifaces
gateways = netifaces.gateways()
default_gateway = gateways['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][0]
print(default_gateway)
```

Which you can can install with `pip install netifaces`. The benefit of this approach is that you don't need to differentiate approaches between Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It is because os.system does not return the stdout.
you should use a sub process.

```
#For Linux
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ip r"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out = p.stdout.read()
print out
```

Answer (score 0):

import socket, struct

def get_default_gateway_linux():

```
"""Read the default gateway directly from /proc."""
with open("/proc/net/route") as fh:

    for line in fh:

        fields = line.strip().split()
        if fields[1] != '00000000' or not int(fields[3], 16) & 2:
            # If not default route or not RTF_GATEWAY, skip it
            continue
        return socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L", int(fields[2], 16)))
```

get_default_gateway_linux()

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34533669)