# Why running a container via docker sdk in python I get different output compared to the actual command line?

Tags: python, docker

In a shell session I have run:

```
 docker run --rm --net host busybox /bin/sh -c "ip route get 1 | sed -n 's/^.*src \([0-9.]*\) .*$/\1/p'"
```

The output of the command is:

```
10.0.2.15
```

But for a utility script that interfaces docker directly using python and [docker-sdk](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) I run the same command as well:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
print(client.containers.run('busybox',["/bin/sh","-c","ip route get 1 | sed -n 's/^.*src \([0-9.]*\) .*$/\1/p'"],remove=True,network="host"))
```

But I get the following output:

```
b'\x01\n'
```

I tried to convert into ascii like this:

```
print(client.containers.run('busybox',["/bin/sh","-c","ip route get 1 | sed -n 's/^.*src \([0-9.]*\) .*$/\1/p'"],remove=True,network="host").decode('ascii'))
```

But seem not to print any printable character despite spaces.  Any idea how I can retrieve the same output using python?

## Edit 1

I also tried to capture the stdout:

```
client.containers.run('busybox',["/bin/sh","-c","ip route get 1 | sed -n 's/^.*src \([0-9.]*\) .*$/\1/p'"],remove=True,network="host",stdout=True)
```

But same result occur.

Though if I ommit the sed part seems to work fine (but having the result not filtered):

```
print(client.containers.run('busybox',["/bin/sh","-c","ip route get 1"],remove=True,network="host"))
```

Prints:

```
b'1.0.0.0 via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3  src 10.0.2.15 \n'
```

Therefore for some reason sed part seems to break the output.

Comment: I do not know but I alsi used the `stdout=True` flad and I got same result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by unescaped `\1` at `sed` part of the command.
In order to work you must do:

```
print(client.containers.run('busybox',"/bin/sh -c \"ip route get 1 | sed -n 's/^.*src \([0-9.]*\) .*$/\\1/p'\"",remove=True,network="host"))
```

Pay attention on this string used as second argument for the functipon:

```
"/bin/sh -c \"ip route get 1 | sed -n 's/^.*src \([0-9.]*\) .*$/\\1/p'\""
#                                                   escaped this ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the escaping problem you describe in your answer by post-processing the output in Python code.  This also means you don't need a shell in your container invocation, which removes a potential level of quoting (and attendant security concerns).

```py
raw_output = client.containers.run('busybox', ['ip', 'route', 'get', '1'], remove=True, network='host')
output = str(raw_output, encoding='utf-8')
lines = output.split('\n')
for l in lines:
  words = l.split()
  try:
    src = words.index('src')
    print(words[src + 1])
  except ValueError: # 'src' not in the list
    pass
  except IndexError: # 'src' is the last word
    pass
```

For this particular case, since you're using the host network and then requesting network information, you're seeing the host's network setup.  If your Docker environment is based on a virtual machine (for example, Docker Desktop) you're seeing that VM's network environment; this is not a portable path to find the host's gateway address.  If you're on a native-Linux system you can often just run this command using the `subprocess` module without involving Docker (the decoding details are otherwise identical to what's in this answer).  [Python: get default gateway for a local interface/ip address in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761829/python-get-default-gateway-for-a-local-interface-ip-address-in-linux) has a number of other approaches that don't require Docker.

Comment: Well the python script created `docker-compose.yml` for php apps and in my vagrant box I run a common smtp server outside any container at host. Therefore, I want to get the ip that a container uses for communicating towards host. Also in my toll I do use docker sdk for other suff as well.