# UDP listener [Errno 99]

Tags: python, sockets, wireshark

In the image, the specs of the UDP package I aim to capture is shown through WireShark. The UDP packet comes from a different client attached to my router. However, when trying to capture this using *socket* through *python*, I keep on getting **OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address**.

Currently I am doing following:

```
import sys
import socket

##Capture UDP packets
UDP_IP = "192.168.13.13"
UDP_PORT = 1667

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)
print(sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)
while True:
    print (sys.stderr, '\nwaiting to receive message')
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)

    print (sys.stderr, 'received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address))
    print (sys.stderr, data)
```

Is this the correct address to use?

[image: Data to capture]

Comment: Of all the pages I read, that wasn't one of them. Thank you!

Comment: Solved! Ip should be set to "" (default) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878625/receiving-broadcast-packets-in-python