# Platform/version independent way to find IP address of all interfaces in my Linux box using only the standard library

Tags: python, linux, sockets, network-programming, ioctl

I don't want to use the `ifconfig` because the output is not same in all distros: I want a consistent way to find the IP address of all the interfaces.

I was planning to get the interface name by parsing the `/proc/net/dev` and then using interface name to find the IP address using the siocgifconf ioctl found [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/439093-get-names-of-all-up-network-interfaces-linux-only/) . But that too is said, not to work on all version of Linux.

I'm looking something that **doesn't use any non-default Python libraries** like `netifaces`. And the ioctl is said not to work in all the versions of Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243276/how-to-get-the-physical-interface-ip-address-from-an-interface (which also has a link to another possible dupe!)

Comment: @AIG I'm looking something that don't use any non-standard libraries. And the ioctl is said not to work in all the versions of Linux, so it's not a duplicate question.

Comment: I don't see how you're going to get much better than `netifaces`, it seems like it was created explicitly to do what you want: be as platform independent as possible. If your favorite distro doesn't work with it, how about filing an issue/pull request?

Comment: @AlG given his stdlib requirement, you pointed to the wrong dupe. At least use the other one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `netifaces` package which can be installed using `easy_install`:

```
from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses, AF_INET
for ifaceName in interfaces():
addresses = [i['addr'] for i in ifaddresses(ifaceName).setdefault(AF_INET, [{'addr':'No IP addr'}] )]
print '%s: %s' % (ifaceName, ', '.join(addresses))
```

Comment: It is not easy to get the address(es) of the machine’s network interfaces in a platform independent way. If you can't use `netifaces`, you may want to check out its source code: https://bitbucket.org/al45tair/netifaces

Answer (score 0):

If your question was "How to get all IP addresses of my computer", I would answer

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
('strauch', [], ['172.16.0.100', '192.168.157.1', '192.168.60.1'])
```

It can not tell the interfaces but uses all of them.

Comment: But it's showing only loopback IP, it's not showing my interface IP which is 192.168.1.3.