# Find IP address on all network interfaces from Python

Tags: python, networking

I would like to find all possible addresses that might identify my computer on all of its network interfaces.  I would like to do this within Python.

For example if I run `ifconfig` on linux I get the following:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
          inet addr:172.25.24.6  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: ... Scope:Link

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: ... Scope:Link
```

I see that my machine identifies as `172.25.24.6`, `127.0.0.1`, and `192.168.1.1`.  How can I get this information in a cross platform way from within Python?

Comment: Seems to answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6250688/5088142

Comment: If possible I'd like to avoid a C dependency.  Is there a way to do this from standard Python?