# Python: Getting Local Nameserver information from Windows 95/XP/7

Tags: python, windows, dns, nameservers

I'm trying to get local nameserver information for a reverse DNS lookup. In Linux I can parse the resolv.conf file. How do I get the same information for Windows programmatically using Python? What I'm looking for is an IP similar to 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.2.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Comment: That finds the localhost's ip. I'm looking for the nameserver which is often the router. It's usually the same subnet with an address of 1, but sometimes it changes.

Comment: Oops!  Sorry.  I should learn not to look at SO just before I leave work so that I read things more carefully.  Anyway, I've not done this sort of thing before, but maybe the netifaces package will help:  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces/0.3 and http://alastairs-place.net/netifaces/