# get city from ip not working on remote server

Tags: php, get, city

get city from IP is not working on remote server but it works in localhost. Does anyone have any better ideas for getting the city from this class? Sometimes the server remote addr displays this:

> ```
>  ::1
> ```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
class iplocation{

  public function ipgetCity(){

    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $addr_details = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=&#8217',$ip));
    $city = stripslashes(ucfirst($addr_details['geoplugin_city']));
    return $city;
} }
```

Comment: ::1 is the ip of localhost, you could make sure that the REMOTE_ADDR is the [the external address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909362/how-do-i-get-the-external-ip-of-my-server-using-php ) and geoplugin doesn't always return a city.

Comment: `file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=&#8217',$ip)` looks wrong, i would expect `file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip)`