# Change site address based on location

Tags: php, wordpress, geolocation

My company has a few different domains, the most simple being a .com to .ca site. How can we create a system that changes the domain based on the users location. For example: if a visitor from the US finds our .ca site on google, how can I redirect them to .com instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you already have some type of geolocation functionality to identify where the visitor is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using html5 geolocation with google maps api and window.location.replace to redirect could be a solution.

```
 window.onload = function () {
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(fnPosition);
   }
}
function fnPosition(position) {
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var long = position.coords.longitude;
   checkCountry(lat,long);
}

function checkCountry(lat,long) {
   var country = {};
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results) {
       if (results[1]) {
           for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
               for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {
                   if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "country") {
                       country =results[0].address_components[i];
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       fnRedirect(country);
   });
}

function fnRedirect(country) {
   switch(country.short_name) {
       case 'CA':
 // some window window.location.replace(...)
 break;
 default:
 // whatever
} 
}
```

I used this example to get the information from the location [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/get-city-name-using-geolocation)

In php, you can get the location based on the ip.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
switch ($details->country) {
    case 'CA':
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    exit;
        break;

    default:
        #whatever
        break;
 }
```

PHP Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909362/how-do-i-get-the-external-ip-of-my-server-using-php)