# Getting the remote IP address in Python

Tags: python

How do I get the remote IP address in Python?

I tried searching Google but couldn't find any useful results. `os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']` is giving `KeyError: 'REMOTE_ADDR'`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: that's wrong. He wants the IP address of a client connecting to his web app, not of the server on which his app is running.

Comment: What does your stack look like?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Debian, Apache 2.2 and Python 2.7

Comment: @Cairnarvon you're right, but can't remove the close vote now.

Comment: @AdamSilver `mod_wsgi`?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're accessing the operating system's `os` environment, not the `request`'s.

The WSGI callable should be passed two variables, `environ` and `start_response`, and that `environ` variable will have the variables you're looking for.

Those variables would only be present in the actual `os.environ` if you were running a `CGI` app.

---

Depending on the web framework you're using, you might not have access to this. If you're passed a `request` object, this will likely end up in `request.META` or something similar.

If you're not using any framework, that will be in [the `environ` dict that is passed to your wsgi callable](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#specification-details).

As noted in another answer, `REMOTE_ADDR` doesn't **have** to be their as per the spec, but if you're using Apache's `mod_wsgi`, it should be there.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, `REMOTE_ADDR` may be the address of a forwarder if your setup has any web application firewall, a proxy that is handling the requests (like nginx) or other such setup. In this case, its also worth checking for the presence of `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the TCP socket, you can use `socket.getpeername()` to get the remote address. [Docs are here.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)