# Python Hostname resolving very slow

Tags: python, sockets, networking, dns, ip

I am currently trying to build a little Networkscan for my home network.
To resolve the hostnames, I want to use this function called within a for loop iterating over a range of IPs. That is doing very well, but I think the `gethostbyaddr(tgtHost)` function is very very slow. Is there a way to speed things up or use alternative functions ?

```
def fn_hostscan(tgtHost):

    response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + tgtHost + "> C:\\temp\log.txt")

    if response == 0:
        try:
            tgtName = gethostbyaddr(tgtHost)
            print("\n[+] " + tgtHost + " = " + tgtName[0])
        except:
            dummy = 0
    else:

    print("\n[-]" + tgtHost + " = None found")
```

Comment: Is there any way I can encourage this question to be closed?

Comment: Yes you can ... sorry I dont know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at whats around for this:

Would this suit your purposes? - 
[Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

```
import socket 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("gmail.com",80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

gethostbyaddr and similar functions are dependant of your resolv.conf (see http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf).

1. your DNS resolver is slow (try using Google's Public DNS)
2. some IPs do not have PTR records or their NS are offline, the default timeout is 5sec - keep that in mind while "looping"

To improve performance you might want to parallelize it, use a fast resolver and keep the timeout setting to a minimum.

If you can, use libs similar to http://c-ares.haxx.se/