# How can I know the ip address of the server?

Tags: python, pygame

I am developing a multiplayer game using python (pygame and podsixnet). Every time the client has to connect to the server, it has to type the server's hostname and port. I want to bypass this stage by automatically providing the client with this information. How can I find the address of my server? The game has been developed by following the tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/38732/multiplayer-game-programming-for-teens-with-python

```
def __init__(self):
    self.justplaced=10
    n = self.dialog()
    print n
    pygame.init()
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Scrabble')
    self.gameid=None
    self.num=None

    self.lastx, self.lasty = 0, 0

    self.mousex = 0 # used to store x coordinate of mouse event
    self.mousey = 0 # used to store y coordinate of mouse event
    #print BGCOLOR

    self.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
    #pygame.display.update()

    self.is_Placed = self.generateBoxData(False)
    self.placed_Letter = self.generateBoxData("")
    self.is_Formed = self.generateBoxData(False)
    self.owner = self.generateBoxData(99)
    self.is_Clicked = self.generateBoxData(False)

    address=raw_input("Address of Server: ")

    try:
        if not address:
            host, port="localhost", 8000
        else:
            host,port=address.split(":")
        self.Connect(("localhost" ,int(port)))
    except:
        print "Error Connecting to Server"
        print "Usage:", "host:port"
        print "e.g.", "localhost:31425"
        exit()
    print "Boxes client started"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Answer (score 0):

I like making maltiplayer games too! :)

This is mostly what you may be looking for **socket.gethostbyname(hostname)**

a full small script would look like this:

```
import socket
hostname = 'maps.google.com'
addr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
print 'The address of ', hostname, 'is', addr
```

Hope this helps!