# Is there any python API which can get the IP address (internal or external) of Virtual machine in Azure

Tags: python, azure

I want to control the VMs in Azure with python SDK. Is there any API that can get a VM's IP address (internal or external) according to VM's name?

Comment: I believe this question may be answered at [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Comment: I mean getting IP address of VMs with Azure python SDK. This is because I want to remote control the VMs in Azure with it's SDK. It's a different question.

Comment: You probably need to clarify the question a bit. Is this from within the VM, or from a control machine somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to get the public & private ip addresses of a Azure VM using Azure SDK for Python.

For getting these ip addresses (internal & external), please see the code below.

```
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient, NetworkManagementClientConfiguration

subscription_id = '33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333'

credentials = ...

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
    NetworkManagementClientConfiguration(
        credentials,
        subscription_id
    )
)

GROUP_NAME = 'XXX'
VM_NAME = 'xxx'
PUBLIC_IP_NAME = VM_NAME

public_ip_address = network_client.public_ip_addresses.get(GROUP_NAME, PUBLIC_IP_NAME)
print(public_ip_address.ip_address)
print(public_ip_address.ip_configuration.private_ip_address)
```

As reference, you can refer to the documents below to know the details of the code above.

1. [Resource Management Authentication](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resourcemanagementauthentication.html) using Python for the variable `credentials`.
2. [Create the management client](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resourcemanagementcomputenetwork.html#create-the-management-client) for the variable `network_client`.
3. More details for the `azure.mgmt.network` package, please see http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.network.html.

Comment: Very convoluted (thank you Microsoft) way of getting IP addresses, but works and saved my day.


Small correction, currently the network_client is created like this:


    network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
        credentials,
        subscription_id
    )

Comment: Hold on. This only works if the public IP address object has the same name as the VM... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

For the people that don't have public IP assigned to their VM there is a way to get the private IP without creating the public IP.

```
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient, NetworkManagementClientConfiguration

subscription_id = '' 
credentials = UserPassCredentials(
    'user@yes.com',
    'password',
)

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)

private_ip = network_client.network_interfaces.get(GROUP_NAME, NETWORK_INTERFACE_NAME).ip_configurations[0].private_ip_address
```

This works and is tested on azure-sdk-for-python version 2.0.0rc6.