# Get IP from VM object using azure sdk in python

Tags: python, azure, cloud

I am trying to get all the IPs (attached to VMs) from an azure subscription.

I have pulled all the VMs using

```
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials,subscription_id)


 for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all():
      print(vm.network_profile.network_interface)
```

But the network_profile object seems to only be a pointer, I have read through the documentation and can not figure out how to link each vm to its attached IP addresses

I came across this: [Is there any python API which can get the IP address (internal or external) of Virtual machine in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265885/is-there-any-python-api-which-can-get-the-ip-address-internal-or-external-of-v)

But it seems that something has changed.

I am able to resolve the IPs of a machine only if I know the name of the Public_IP address object(Which not all of them have public IPs).

I need to be able to take this network_interface and resolve the IP on it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So It seems that in order to get the IPs, you need to parse the URI given in the `vm.network_profile.network_interface`. Then use the the subscription and the nic name to get the IP `using network_client.network_interfaces.get()`.

The code I used is below:

```
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials,subscription_id)
        try:
            get_private(compute_client, network_client)
        except:
            print("Auth failed on "+ subscription_id)



def get_private(compute_client, network_client):


    for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all():
        for interface in vm.network_profile.network_interfaces:
            name=" ".join(interface.id.split('/')[-1:])
            sub="".join(interface.id.split('/')[4])

            try:
                thing=network_client.network_interfaces.get(sub, name).ip_configurations

                for x in thing:
                    print(x.private_ip_address)

            except:
                print("nope")
```

In this example you could also do `x.public_ip_address` to get the public IPs

Comment: I tried this. The code works but the public ip address is returning None value.

Answer (score 1):

As your said, indeed, something has changed, but not much.

First as below, `NetworkManagementClientConfiguration` has been remove, see the details in the [link](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resourcemanagementcomputenetwork.html#create-the-management-client).

```
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials,subscription_id)
```

Second, according to the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-mgmt-network/azure/mgmt/network/operations/public_ip_addresses_operations.py#L120), the parameter `public_ip_address_name` is the name of the subnet, cease to be the vm name.

```
# Resource Group
GROUP_NAME = 'azure-sample-group-virtual-machines'
# Network
SUBNET_NAME = 'azure-sample-subnet'
PUBLIC_IP_NAME = SUBNET_NAME
public_ip_address = network_client.public_ip_addresses.get(GROUP_NAME, PUBLIC_IP_NAME)
```

Then, you can also the `private_ip_address` & `public_ip_address` via the [`IPConfiguration`](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.network.models.html#azure.mgmt.network.models.IPConfiguration) from the [`PublicIPAddress`](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.network.models.html#azure.mgmt.network.models.PublicIPAddress)

```
print(public_ip_address.ip_configuration.private_ip_address)
print(public_ip_address.ip_configuration.public_ip_address)
```

Comment: Hi, to complete Peter Pan solution, the only way to get IPs from a VM is to get the IDs in the VM properties, and then to parse the IDs to get the different part inside (Resource Group, Subnet, etc.), and then to call the network client. This might help: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/534