# What is custom_headers in azure python sdk methods?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to find public IP address attached to running Azure VM.

I've tried both answers as per [Get IP from VM object using azure sdk in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728871/get-ip-from-vm-object-using-azure-sdk-in-python) but I'm not getting required output.
Getting Public IP: None

```
    ...:     for interface in vm.network_profile.network_interfaces:
    ...:         name=" ".join(interface.id.split('/')[-1:])
    ...:         print (name)
    ...:         sub="".join(interface.id.split('/')[4])
    ...:         print (sub)
    ...:         thing = network_client.network_interfaces.get(sub, name).ip_configurations
    ...:         for x in thing:
    ...:             print (x.public_ip_address)
    ...:
xxx
xxx
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/Test-ip', 'name': None, 'type': None, 'location': None, 'tags': None, 'sku': None, 'public_ip_allocation_method': None, 'public_ip_address_version': None, 'ip_configuration': None, 'dns_settings': None, 'ddos_settings': None, 'ip_tags': None, 'ip_address': None, 'public_ip_prefix': None, 'idle_timeout_in_minutes': None, 'resource_guid': None, 'provisioning_state': None, 'etag': None, 'zones': None}
```

whereas using network_client I'm getting output

```
In [6]: from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
In [21]: for i in network_client.public_ip_addresses.list("xxx"):
    ...:     print (i)
```

But here I'm getting output for all subscriptions, all resource group which basically I want to filter.
Hence I think using custom_headers we may filter, but I'm not getting what would be the exact naming convention of dict I'd create for custom_headers.

- How can I get full list of available custom_headers ?
- Also can someone please share some example of listing and getting All Details of running/stopped VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: Your question has been addressed on Github already:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/897

A few comments though:

- `custom_headers` is to define HTTP headers, which won't help for your scenario:
- By design, when you create a `NetworkManagementClient` you already filter by subscription, since subscription is a parameter of it.
- The parameter of `public_ip_addresses.list` is a resource group name, so you already filter by resource group name: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2019_04_01.operations.publicipaddressesoperations?view=azure-python#list-resource-group-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-
- Your first code is fine, but you need to re-inject the public IP id into `public_ip_addresses.get`. NIC doesn't expand to the actual Public IP value for computational reason.

(I work at MS in the Python SDK team)

Comment: Laurent Mazuel - Thanks for the detailed reply. Yes this is very helpful info. and solved the issue as well.Thanks again.