# How can I resolve the following error, "code": "NoRegisteredProviderFound" in Azure when I am using azurerm in Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python, azure-rm

I am using the following azurerm function in my code:

```
public_ips = azurerm.get_vmss_public_ips(access_token, SUBSCRIPTION_ID, 
GROUP_NAME, CUScaleSet)

print(public_ips)
```

I am getting the following output:

> {u'error': {u'message': u"No registered resource provider found for
>   location 'eastus' and API version '2019-03-01' for type
>   'virtualMachineScaleSets/publicIPAddresses'. The supported
>   api-versions are '2017-03-30, 2017-12-01, 2018-04-01, 2018-06-01,
>   2018-10-01'. The supported locations are 'eastus, eastus2, westus,
>   centralus, northcentralus, southcentralus, northeurope, westeurope,
>   eastasia, southeastasia, japaneast, japanwest, australiaeast,
>   australiasoutheast, australiacentral, brazilsouth, southindia,
>   centralindia, westindia, canadacentral, canadaeast, westus2,
>   westcentralus, uksouth, ukwest, koreacentral, koreasouth,
>   francecentral, southafricanorth, uaenorth'.", u'code':
>   u'NoRegisteredProviderFound'}}

NOTE: The same piece of code was running a few days ago.

Comment: I see that you want to get the public ip of your VM's .You can try something like here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728871/get-ip-from-vm-object-using-azure-sdk-in-python  Also check this https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/897

Comment: I will suggest you use the official Azure SDK for python of VMSS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.operations.virtualmachinescalesetsoperations?view=azure-python).

Comment: I want to get IP of the VM in a Virtual Machine Scale Set. Not the VM in a Resource Group.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is to fetch all the IPs of the VMs in the VMSS instance, you can use the official [Azure SDK for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) as follows:

```
# Imports
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient

# Set subscription ID
SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'


def get_credentials():
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id='xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        secret='xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        tenant='xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    )

    return credentials


# Get credentials
credentials = get_credentials()


# Initialize management client
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
    credentials,
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID
)


def get_vmss_vm_ips():

    # List all network interfaces of the VMSS instance
    vmss_nics = network_client.network_interfaces.list_virtual_machine_scale_set_network_interfaces(
        "<VMSS Resource group name>", "<VMSS instance name>")

    niclist = [nic.serialize() for nic in vmss_nics]

    print "IP addresses in the given VM Scale Set:"

    for nic in niclist:
        ipconf = nic['properties']['ipConfigurations']

        for ip in ipconf:
            print ip['properties']['privateIPAddress']


# Get all IPs of VMs in VMSS
get_vmss_vm_ips()
```

**References:**

- [NetworkInterfacesOperations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2019_04_01.operations.networkinterfacesoperations?view=azure-python) class
- [list_virtual_machine_scale_set_network_interfaces()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2019_04_01.operations.networkinterfacesoperations?view=azure-python#list-virtual-machine-scale-set-network-interfaces-resource-group-name--virtual-machine-scale-set-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) method

Hope this helps!