# Find the Infiniband IP Address of an Azure VM

Tags: python, azure, hpc, azure-sdk-python

This is similar to [Is there any python API which can get the IP address (internal or external) of Virtual machine in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265885/is-there-any-python-api-which-can-get-the-ip-address-internal-or-external-of-v/37269169), but instead I'd like to get the infiniband IP address of an azure VM.

So far, I can get the NIC of the VM in the VMSS, but that only lets me query for the private IP address of eth0.  How can I get the IP addresses of the other interfaces?

Ideally, I'd like to do this in Python

```
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
self.network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials, AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

# get the private IP of a network interface
nic_name = 'redacted'
network_client.network_interfaces.get(GROUP_NAME, nic_name)
private_ip = nic.ip_configurations[0].private_ip_address
```

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to fetch all the IPs of the VMs/Network interfaces in the VMSS instance, you can use the official [Azure SDK for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) as follows:

```
# Imports
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient

# Set subscription ID
SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'


def get_credentials():
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id='xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        secret='xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        tenant='xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    )

    return credentials


# Get credentials
credentials = get_credentials()


# Initialize management client
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
    credentials,
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID
)


def get_vmss_vm_ips():

    # List all network interfaces of the VMSS instance
    vmss_nics = network_client.network_interfaces.list_virtual_machine_scale_set_network_interfaces(
        "<VMSS Resource group name>", "<VMSS instance name>")

    niclist = [nic.serialize() for nic in vmss_nics]

    print "IP addresses in the given VM Scale Set:"

    for nic in niclist:
        ipconf = nic['properties']['ipConfigurations']

        for ip in ipconf:
            print ip['properties']['privateIPAddress']


# Get all IPs of VMs in VMSS
get_vmss_vm_ips()
```

Note that the [`network_client.network_interfaces.get()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2015_06_15.operations.networkinterfacesoperations?view=azure-python#get-resource-group-name--network-interface-name--expand-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) method gets information about the specified network interface only whereas the [`list_virtual_machine_scale_set_network_interfaces()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2015_06_15.operations.networkinterfacesoperations?view=azure-python#list-virtual-machine-scale-set-network-interfaces-resource-group-name--virtual-machine-scale-set-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) method fetches all network interfaces in a virtual machine scale set.

**References:**

- [NetworkInterfacesOperations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2019_04_01.operations.networkinterfacesoperations?view=azure-python) class
- [list_virtual_machine_scale_set_network_interfaces()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2019_04_01.operations.networkinterfacesoperations?view=azure-python#list-virtual-machine-scale-set-network-interfaces-resource-group-name--virtual-machine-scale-set-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) method

Hope this helps! Please let me know if otherwise and we can explore further.