# Communication between multiple docker-compose projects

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two separate `docker-compose.yml` files in two different folders:

- `~/front/docker-compose.yml`
- `~/api/docker-compose.yml`

How can I make sure that a container in `front` can send requests to a container in `api`?

I know that `--default-gateway` option can be set using `docker run` for an individual container, so that a specific IP address can be assigned to this container, but it seems that this option is not available when using `docker-compose`.

Currently I end up doing a `docker inspect my_api_container_id` and look at the gateway in the output. It works but the problem is that this IP is randomly attributed, so I can't rely on it.

Another form of this question might thus be:

- Can I attribute a fixed IP address to a particular container using docker-compose?

But in the end what I'm looking after is:

- How can two different docker-compose projects communicate with each other?

Comment: I just looked into this today again.  The devs have finally relented and allowed arbitrary network naming.  Using compose file version 3.5 you can specify a name for the default network under the 'networks' key.  This will create a named network without the usual project name prefix if it doesn't exist..

Comment: be aware of what kind of connection you're planning to set. one-way (A->B or B->A; described in this question) or bidirectional A <-> B which is harder to achieve (requires wrapping docker files with extra logic and verifying whether the network exists or not due to mutual dependencies)

Answer (score 743, accepted):

You just need to make sure that the containers you want to talk to each other are on the same network. Networks are a first-class docker construct, and not specific to compose.

```yaml
# front/docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  front:
    ...
    networks:
      - some-net
networks:
  some-net:
    driver: bridge
```

...

```yaml
# api/docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    ...
    networks:
      - front_some-net
networks:
  front_some-net:
    external: true
```

> Note: Your app’s network is given a name based on the “project name”, which is based on the name of the directory it lives in, in this case a prefix `front_` was added

They can then talk to each other using the service name. From `front` you can do `ping api` and vice versa.

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't anything mapped to the host port (localhost), be visible to all the containers?

Comment: And once they are ensured to be in the same network, as you suggest, what to do then? Can `front` container have a `link` to `api` container for instance?

Comment: @JHarris well, if I do what you suggest, starting (`up`) ~/front triggers `Some networks were defined but are not used by any service` - while starting ~/api triggers `Service "api" uses an undefined network`

Comment: @RobertMoskal actually, if you turn your comment to an answer, I'll accept it because it was in this case the way to go (just add the `dockerhost` mention evoked [in this thread](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23177)).

Comment: Jivan that's a non-solution. Your containers should not need to know anything about the host or be manipulated like that. My answer was pretty short though, I have updated with more detail.

Comment: Robert Moskal only if you hack around to get the ip of your docker host into the containers. Better to have them communicate on a common docker-defined network.

Comment: @JHarris trying your solution -- do you have to manually create the network beforehand (with `docker network create some-net`)? -- asking this because `compose` replies with `ERROR: Network some-net declared as external, but could not be found.`

Comment: You either gotta create beforehand, or name it front_some-net (compose prefixes the project name -- front -- to any resources it creates).

Comment: @JHarris it worked - thanks. However, when I try to put `nginx` into the mix, it doesn't -- see [my new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125313/docker-network-and-nginx-failed-while-connecting-to-upstream) if you have some time ;)

Comment: Please note that the "front_" prefix to the network is created automatically from the folder its running on. So if your first docker-compose file would be located in "example/docker-compose.yml" it would be called "example_default" instead.

Comment: You can also provide a name to a network using `name` property, which will disable automatic prepending with project name. Then either project can use that network and create it automatically if it does not yet exist.

Comment: @SteveB - Note that the name property only works from docker-compose files version 3.5 and up

Comment: @kramer65 True, and name property also is available since 2.1 for version 2.

Comment: Just curious,
what happen if we have same service name but on different network,
can the caller container, be more explicit about which network it want to use to call a particular service?

Comment: It seems to me like inverted: why is it the front end config that creates the network?

I have a mongdb in my backend that should be consumed both by the frontend and backend server. I cannot create it twice (once per consumer). How should I do?

I created a more detailed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68589288/how-to-connect-to-named-networks-in-docker-compose

Comment: @AltianoGerung: I think you could create alias for that service. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#aliases .Also, to my mind it could be cool if that service will be available like: `service_name.stack_name`, eg. like usual domain name services. So here we specifically said that `service_name` is from `stack_name` stack.

Answer (score 276):

UPDATE:  As of compose file version 3.5:

This now works:

```yaml
version: "3.5"
services:
  proxy:
    image: hello-world
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - proxynet

networks:
  proxynet:
    name: custom_network
```

`docker-compose up -d` will join a network called 'custom_network'.  If it doesn't exist, it will be created!

```sh
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-tor1-01:~# docker-compose up -d
Creating network "custom_network" with the default driver
Creating root_proxy_1 ... done
```

Now, you can do this:

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    image: hello-world
    networks:
      - my-proxy-net
networks:
  my-proxy-net:
    external:
      name: custom_network
```

This will create a container that will be on the external network.

I can't find any reference in the docs yet but it works!

Comment: Do you have to start the two services in a specific order?  Can you start either one, and the first one will create the network and the second one will join it?

Comment: The first service (proxy above) creates the network.  The syntax in the second example joins it.

Comment: @slashdottir You can **not** mark the network as external in second service and it will be created if it does not yet exist.

Comment: It's not creating network if it does not exists. `ERROR: Network network declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the network manually using `docker network create network` and try again.`

Comment: It does work.  I just spun up a DO droplet with the latest docker compose.  I have edited the example to an actual working example.

Comment: Here are the refs in the docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network

Comment: In my case, this turned out to be a more suitable solution than the accepted answer. The problem with external network was, that it required to start containers in predefined order. For my client, this was not acceptable. A named network (since 3.5) turned out to be perfect solution. Thanks.

Comment: Network naming is insensitive - if your compose lives in `DIR` still a `dir_network` will be created.

Comment: One thing this answers missed is where to find the host domain.
1. Bash into the container.
2. Run `/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'` it will print the IP. This IP is the same one for all the services connected to the same network

If you'd like to have a custom host domain, just run something like: `echo "${HOST_IP} my-custom-domain.dev.com" | tee -a /etc/hosts`
This will add it to the `/etc/hosts` file and you can use `my-custom-domain.dev.com` to connect to your other service

Comment: Additionally you can add `external_links: - proxy` to the `web` service to make the dependency more explicit (like one would use `depends_on` if they are in the same docker-compose file.

Comment: @cstrutton do you have an idea as to how best to set say a URL in container 2 to fetch data from cont  1 instead of manually using IP addresses?

Comment: Seems it does not work with different profiles and still adds the profile name in front. Will probably need to split my compose file into one profile and one independent part.

Comment: Doesn't this configuration cause problems when you need to do `docker-compose down` for only one of your compose projects, while the other is still running? I think it will try to remove the network while it is still in use by the other compose project and crash.

Comment: No need to use IPs. Just use http://proxy:80 to access hello-world image. Make sure to do `docker inspect containerid` and check Aliases property for all urls.

Answer (score 127):

Just a small adittion to @johnharris85's great answer,
when you are running a docker compose file, a "`default`" network is created
so you can just add it to the other compose file as an external network:

```
# front/docker-compose.yml 
version: '2' 
  services:   
    front_service:
    ...
```

...

```
# api/docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  api_service:
    ...
    networks:
      - front_default
networks:
  front_default:
    external: true
```

For me this approach was more suited because I did not own the first docker-compose file and wanted to communicate with it.

Comment: just wandering the correct way to assign static IP for this external network. I manged to do it within `services:` tag, the sintax would be `networks:` then nested `front_default:` (remove the "-") and then we nest a static IP: `ipv4_address: '172.20.0.44'`

Comment: Although this is true, there may come a time when this does not work.  You are relying on an implementation detail.  Who is to say that they won't change the way default networks are named in a future version.  Creating an explicitly named network is documented and will likely be supported for some time.

Comment: @cstrutton The default network name is also documented.

Answer (score 47):

All containers from `api` can join the `front` *default* network with following config:

```
# api/docker-compose.yml

...

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: front_default
```

See docker compose guide: [using a pre existing network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network) (see at the bottom)

Answer (score 46):

Everybody has explained really well, so I'll add the necessary code with just one simple explanation.

**Use a network created outside of docker-compose (an "external" network) with** `docker-compose` version `3.5+`.

[Further explanation can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42750687/6332074)

*First* `docker-compose.yml` file should define network with name `giveItANamePlease` as follows.

```
networks:
  my-network:
    name: giveItANamePlease
    driver: bridge
```

The services of first `docker-compose.yml` file can use network as follows:

```
networks:
  - my-network
```

In *second* `docker-compose` file, we need to proxy the network by using the network name which we have used in first `docker-compose` file, which in this case is `giveItANamePlease`:

```
networks:
  my-proxy-net:
    external:
      name: giveItANamePlease
```

And now you can use `my-proxy-net` in services of a second `docker-compose.yml` file as follows.

```
networks:
  - my-proxy-net
```

Comment: Finally a modern/easy-to-use answer

Comment: Make the `networks` section in the second file match the first (remove reference to `external`) and it won't matter which project starts first (allow either to auto-create the network)

Comment: Thank you very much!!) in new syntax:

networks:
  proxy-name-net:
    name: mynetwork-net
    external: true

Answer (score 29):

The previous posts information is correct, but it does not have details on how to link containers, which should be connected as "external_links".

Hope this example make more clear to you:

- Suppose you have app1/docker-compose.yml, with two services (svc11 and svc12), and app2/docker-compose.yml with two more services (svc21 and svc22) and suppose you need to connect in a crossed fashion:
- svc11 needs to connect to svc22's container
- svc21 needs to connect to svc11's container.

So the configuration should be like this:

**this is app1/docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'
services:
    svc11:
        container_name: container11
        [..]
        networks:
            - default # this network
            - app2_default # external network
        external_links:
            - container22:container22
        [..]
    svc12:
       container_name: container12
       [..]

networks:
    default: # this network (app1)
        driver: bridge
    app2_default: # external network (app2)
        external: true
```

**this is app2/docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'
services:
    svc21:
        container_name: container21
        [..]
        networks:
            - default # this network (app2)
            - app1_default # external network (app1)
        external_links:
            - container11:container11
        [..]
    svc22:
       container_name: container22
       [..]

networks:
    default: # this network (app2)
        driver: bridge
    app1_default: # external network (app1)
        external: true
```

Comment: Thank you for this details explanation in docker network it is very useful. Whole day I was struggling for proper explanation and solution but now I understood the concept.

Comment: Yes it does. I am using this configuration from 2 to 3.7

Comment: "Links" became an obsolete Docker concept once Docker networks were introduced and Compose file version 2 made them available.  If you do have an `external_links:` option as suggested in this answer, it's probably safe to delete it.

Answer (score 19):

So many answers!

First of all, **avoid hyphens** in entities names such as services and networks. They cause issues with name resolution.

Example: `my-api` won't work. `myapi` or `api` will work.

What worked for me is:

```
# api/docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    ...
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: mynetwork
```

and

```
# front/docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  front:
    container_name: front
    ...
    ports:
      - 81:80
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: mynetwork
```

**NOTE**: I added ports to show how services can access each other, and how they are accessible from the host.

**IMPORTANT**: If you don't specify a network `name`, `docker-compose` will craft one for you. It uses the name of the folder the `docker_compose.yml` file is in. In this case: `api_mynetwork` and `front_mynetwork`. That will prevent communication between containers since they will by on different network, with very similar names.

Note that the network is defined exactly the same in both file, so you can start either service first and it will work. No need to specify which one is external, `docker-compose` will take care of managing that for you.

### From the host

You can access either container using the **published ports** defined in `docker-compose.yml`.

You can access the Front container: `curl http://localhost:81`

You can access the API container: `curl http://localhost:8081`

### From the API container

You can access the Front container using the **original port**, not the one you published in `docker-compose.yml`.

Example: `curl http://front:80`

### From the Front container

You can access the API container using the **original port**, not the one you published in `docker-compose.yml`.

Example: `curl http://api:8080`

Comment: Seems like name attribute was added from version `3.5`. Executing `docker network list`  shows the correct network name. Thanks!

Comment: @Gael I've just tried to test your solution to connect Laravel (sail up) as api and vue as front projects. But looks like there are still two different containers and no connections between them. Have you test these frameworks together?

Comment: @Andrew No I have never tried those. Try `docker ps` to see what container are running and what ports are open, to make sure you have set the ports properly.

Comment: The most simple config to connect two (or more) docker compose projects.

Comment: `my-api` service name resolution works well in `version: '3.9'`

Answer (score 16):

Since Compose 1.18 (spec 3.5), you can just override the default network using your own custom name for all Compose YAML files you need. It is as simple as appending the following to them:

```
networks:
  default:
    name: my-app
```

> The above assumes you have `version` set to `3.5` (or above if they don't deprecate it in 4+).

Other answers have pointed the same; this is a simplified summary.

Comment: important to note here is that the identifier of the network is still `default`. you are not able to set `aliases` or something like that to the network `my-app`. You need to use `default` instead

Comment: Adding to the above comment from @gustavz, using `default` as the network identifier allows not needing to specify a network to use in services. The default network **name** `my-app` could be anything to help group multiple Compose services.

Comment: Beware that all of the services are also accessible by their keys as aliases on this same network and there is no guarantee which will resolve for a particular request. See the note in the `aliases` section here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks

Answer (score 11):

UPDATE: As of docker-compose file version 3.5:

I came across a similar problem and I solved it by adding a small change in one of my docker-compose.yml project.

For instance, we have two API's `scoring` and `ner`. `Scoring` API needs to send a request to the `ner` API for processing the input request. In order to do that they both are supposed to share the same network.

**Note:** Every container has its own network which is automatically created at the time of running the app inside docker. For example ner API network will be created like `ner_default` and scoring API network will be named as `scoring default`. This solution will work for version: '3'.

As in the above scenario, my scoring API wants to communicate with ner API then I will add the following lines. This means Whenever I create the container for ner API then it automatically added to the scoring_default network.

```
networks:
  default:
      external:
        name: scoring_default
```

## ner/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  ner:
    container_name: "ner_api"
    build: .
    ...

networks:
  default:
      external:
        name: scoring_default
```

## scoring/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ...
```

We can see this how the above containers are now a part of the same network called  `scoring_default` using the command:

> docker inspect scoring_default

```
{
    "Name": "scoring_default",
        ....
    "Containers": {
    "14a6...28bf": {
        "Name": "ner_api",
        "EndpointID": "83b7...d6291",
        "MacAddress": "0....",
        "IPv4Address": "0.0....",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    "7b32...90d1": {
        "Name": "scoring_api",
        "EndpointID": "311...280d",
        "MacAddress": "0.....3",
        "IPv4Address": "1...0",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice now if u want scoring_api to talk to ner_api would it be `http://scoring_api:port`? or should it still be localhost?

Comment: both apps can use their names to communicate with each other. For example, the scoring app can call ner app using "http://ner_api:port/extract" and vice versa

Comment: Thank you very much for `docker inspect`  and pointing that endpoints should be accessed by *containers name*_ not by _localhost_!

Answer (score 7):

You can add a `.env` file in all your projects containing `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=somename`.

[COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) overrides the prefix used to name resources, as such all your projects will use `somename_default` as their network, making it possible for services to communicate with each other as they were in the same project.

NB: You'll get warnings for "orphaned" containers created from other projects.

Comment: This is a fantastic tip, thanks a ton!

Comment: This idea blows my mind, I think this is truly the right way for these tasks. Just a note, we can specify the project name using -p during docker compose up. Also now it could be a part of docker-compose file with `name:` field

Answer (score 5):

> For using another docker-compose network you just do these(to share networks between docker-compose):
>
> 1. Run the first docker-compose project by `up -d`
> 2. Find the network name of the first docker-compose by: `docker network ls`(It contains the name of the root directory project)
> 3. Then use that name by this structure at below in the second docker-compose file.

second docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  service-on-second-compose:  # Define any names that you want.
    .
    .
    .
    networks:
      - <put it here(the network name that comes from "docker network ls")>

networks:
  - <put it here(the network name that comes from "docker network ls")>:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 5):

To connect two docker-compose you need a network and putting both docker-composes in that network,
you could create netwrok with **docker network create name-of-network**,

or you could simply put network declaration in **networks** option of docker-compose file and when you run docker-compose (docker-compose up) the network would be created automatically.

put the below lines in both docker-compose files

```
networks:
   net-for-alpine:
     name: test-db-net
```

Note: **net-for-alpine** is internal name of the network and it will be used inside of the docker-compose files and could be different,
**test-db-net** is external name of the network and must be same in two docker-compose files.

Assume we have docker-compose.db.yml and docker-compose.alpine.yml

docker-compose.apline.yml would be:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  alpine:
    image: alpine:3.14
    container_name: alpine
    networks:
      - net-for-alpine
  
    # these two command keeps apline container running
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true # docker run -t



networks:
  net-for-alpine:
    name: test-db-net
```

docker-compose.db.yml would be:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:13.4-alpine
    container_name: psql
    networks:
      - net-for-db
  
networks:
  net-for-db:
    name: test-db-net
```

To test the network, go inside alpine container

```
docker exec -it alpine sh
```

then with following commands you could check the network

```
# if it returns 0 or see nothing as a result, network is established
nc -z psql (container name)
```

or

```
ping pgsql
```

Answer (score 4):

I would ensure all containers are `docker-compose`'d to the same network by composing them together at the same time, using:

```
docker compose --file ~/front/docker-compose.yml --file ~/api/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Comment: Will that allow me, for instance, to make a `link` or `depends_on` from one container of front to one container of api?

Comment: actually when I do what you suggest, docker-compose replies either `build path ~/front/api either does not exist or is not accessible` or with the other way around, `build path ~/api/front either does not exist or is not accessible`

Comment: If you're composing them at the same time you shouldn't need to. A network will be created with all your containers on it, they will all be able to communicate via the service name from the compose file (*not* the container name).

Comment: It might be easier if the two compose files are in the same folder. But I don't think that's necessary - I think it should work either way.

Comment: [here is a picture of what I have](http://imgur.com/2zHsVOj) - `front/dc_yml` is on the left and `api/dc.yml` is on the right

Comment: Why does docker-compose insists on searching for `api` build path in `~/front` or for `app` build path in `~/api`?

Comment: I think you're right. Either the volumes, or some other complexity to do with the compose file paths and the fact that it's using Dockerfiles too. I would advise cutting out the volumes sections and putting them back one by one so you can be sure if what's working and what's not. And maybe pre-build your image rather than relying on compose to do it, to reduce complexity to begin with.

Comment: This solution does not work, see my comment on this thread: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3530#issuecomment-222490501

Comment: This solution does not work as, I also thought first, expected. It does not launch both docker-compose instance "together", docker-compose will overlay first file with the second one. So path from second file will be relative to first one file emplacement.

Comment: In order to use this solution, you must have the same version for the YML files.

Answer (score 3):

If you are

- trying to communicate between two containers from **different docker-compose projects** and **don't want to use the same network** (because let's say they would have PostgreSQL or Redis container on the same port and you would prefer to not changing these ports and not use it at the same network)
- developing locally and want to imitate communication between **two docker compose projects**
- running two docker-compose projects on localhost
- developing especially Django apps or Django Rest Framework (drf) API and running app inside container on some exposed port
- getting `Connection refused` while trying to communicate between two containers

And you want to

- container `api_a` communicate to `api_b` (or vice versa) without the same "docker network"

**(example below)**

you can use "host" of the second container as IP of your computer and port that is mapped from inside Docker container. You can obtain IP of your computer with this script (from: [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)):

```
import socket
def get_ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        # doesn't even have to be reachable
        s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
        IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    except:
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    return IP
```

Example:

`project_api_a/docker-compose.yml`:

```
networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  api:
    container_name: api_a
    image: api_a:latest
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    networks:
      - app-tier
```

inside `api_a` container you are running Django app:
`manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

and second docker-compose.yml from other project:

`project_api_b/docker-compose-yml` :

```
networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  api:
    container_name: api_b
    image: api_b:latest
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    networks:
      - app-tier
```

inside `api_b` container you are running Django app:
`manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001`

And trying to connect from container `api_a` to `api_b` then URL of `api_b` container will be:
`http://<get_ip_from_script_above>:8001/`

It can be especially valuable if you are using even more than two(three or more) docker-compose projects and it's hard to provide common network for all of it - it's good workaround and solution

Answer (score 3):

I'm running multiple identical docker-compose.yml files in different directories, using .env files to make a slight difference. And use Nginx Proxy Manage to communicate with other services.  here is my file:

make sure you have created a public network

```
docker network create nginx-proxy-man
```

**/domain1.com/docker-compose.yml, /domain2.com/docker-compose.yml, ...**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  webserver:
    build:
      context: ./bin/${PHPVERSION}
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-${PHPVERSION}"
    ...
    networks:
      - default    # network outside
      - internal   # network internal
  database:
    build:
      context: "./bin/${DATABASE}"
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-${DATABASE}"
    ...
    networks:
      - internal   # network internal


networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: nginx-proxy-man
  internal:
    internal: true
```

**.env file just change `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`**

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=domain1_com
.
.
.
PHPVERSION=php56

DATABASE=mysql57
```

webserver.container_name: domain1_com-php56 - will join the default network (name: nginx-proxy-man), previously created for Nginx Proxy Manager to be accessible from the outside.

**Note: container_name is unique in the same network.**

database.container_name: domain1_com-mysql57 - easier to distinguish

In the same docker-compose.yml, the services will connect to each other via the service name because of the same network domain1_com_internal. And to be more secure, set this network with the option `internal: true`

*Note, if you don't explicitly specify networks for each service, but just use a common external network for both docker-compose.yml, then it's likely that domain1_com will use domain2_com's database.*

Answer (score 1):

Follow up of JohnHarris answer, just adding some more details which may be useful to someone: Lets take two docker-compose file and connect them through networks:

1. 1st foldername/docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  some-contr:
    container_name: []
    build: .
    ...
    networks:
      - somenet
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      # Opens port 8080 on the container
      - "8080"
    environment:
      PORT: 8080
    tty: true
networks:
  boomnet:
    driver: bridge
```

2. 2nd docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services: 
  pushapiserver:
    container_name: [container_name]
    build: .
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"
    volumes:
      - ./:/[work_dir]
    working_dir: /[work dir]
    image: [name of image]
    ports:
      - "8060:8066"
    environment:
      PORT: 8066
    tty: true
    networks:
      - foldername_somenet
networks:
  foldername_somenet:
    external: true
```

Now you can make api calls to one another services(b/w diff containers)like:
http://pushapiserver:8066/send_push call from some code in files for 1st docker-compose.yml

Two common mistakes (atleast i made them few times):

1. take note of [foldername] in which your docker-compose.yml file is present. Please see above in 2nd docker-compose.yml i have added foldername in network bc docker create network by [foldername]_[networkname]
2. Port: this one is very common. Please note i have used 8066 when trying to make connection i.e. http://pushapiserver:8066/... 8066 is port of docker container(2nd docker-compose.yml) so when trying to talk with different docker compose.

> docker will use docker container port[8066] and not host machine mapped port
> [8060]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is just running up the first module with the 'docker-compose' check the ip related with the module, and connect the second module with the previous net like external, and pointing the internal ip

example
app1 - new-network created in the service lines, mark as external: true at the bottom
app2 - indicate the "new-network" created by app1 when goes up,  mark as external: true at the bottom, and set in the config to connect, the ip that app1 have in this net.

With this, you should be able to talk with each other

*this way is just for local-test focus, in order to don't do an over complex configuration
** I know is very 'patch way' but works for me and I think is so simple some other can take advantage of this

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar example where I was working with separate docker-compose files working on a docker swarm with an overlay network to do that all I had to do is change the **networks** parameters as so:

first **docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
version: '3.9'
.
.
.

networks:
  net:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

```sh
docker-compose -p app up
```

since I have specified the app name as `app` using `-p` the initial network will be **app_net**.
Now in order to run another docker-compose with multiple services that will use the same network you will need to set these as so:

second **docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
version: '3.9'
.
.
.
networks:
  net-ref:
    external: true
    name: app_net
```

```sh
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack
```

No matter what name you give to the stack the network will not be affected and will always refer to the existing external network called `app_net`.

> > PS: It's important to make sure to check your docker-compose version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses IP Addresses. The first docker compose should create the network that future containers can join. Here is a snippet code snippet.

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: "jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest"
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "81:81"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      customnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.10
networks:
  customnetwork:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
```

The second docker-compose should join the network that was created:

```
version: "3"
services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    container_name: portainer
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9443:9443
    volumes:
      - portainer_data:/data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      nginxproxymanager_customnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.11
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  portainer_data:
networks:
  nginxproxymanager_customnetwork:
    external: true
```

Source: [WordPress/MYSQL Docker Compose with Networking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvYz_gdlQLE)

Comment: You should almost never need to manually set the container-private IP addresses and that's not necessary for this setup.

Answer (score 0):

All the previous answers is related to the old version of the docker-compose. I am using 3.8 version of docker compose and I have implemented this for the kafka consumer and producer but you can do the same for the other things as well.

So, here is, how i achived this

**Kafka Consumer file**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.10
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_PORT: 2181
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zookeeper:2888:3888
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "echo ruok | nc localhost 2181 | grep imok" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - kafkaNet

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.1.4
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:19093,EXTERNAL://127.0.0.1:9093
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 1
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "kafka-broker-api-versions --bootstrap-server kafka:19093" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    hostname: google.kafka.local.com
    networks:
      - kafkaNet

networks:
  kafkaNet:
    driver: bridge
    name: kafkanetwork
```

Now you can see, I added the hostname as

> google.kafka.local.com

so, this is the url which I am using on the different docker compose code files to avoid to write the hard coded ip address of this container again-again.

**Kafka Producer file**

```
version: '3.8'
 
services:

  awsapi:
    build:
      dockerfile: apis.Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - "1235:1325"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - awsapinetwork

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysqlDb
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_DATABASE_USER_NAME}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - "3305:3306"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./sql/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql:ro
      - ./sql/world.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/world.sql:ro
    networks:
      - awsapinetwork

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadminpanel
    links:
      - mysqldb
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysqldb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8085:80
    networks:
      - awsapinetwork
volumes:
  dbdata:

networks:
  awsapinetwork:
    external: true
    name: kafkanetwork
```

Now I can send the data to kafka consumer container throught the simple network request from awsapi container

> curl google.kafka.local.com:9093

Answer (score -2):

```
version: '2'
services:
  bot:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - '.:/home/node'
      - /home/node/node_modules
    networks:
      - my-rede
    mem_limit: 100m
    memswap_limit: 100m
    cpu_quota: 25000
    container_name: 236948199393329152_585042339404185600_bot
    command: node index.js
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
networks:
  my-rede:
    external:
      name: name_rede_externa
```