# How to set interface name for docker container when connect it to docker bridge?

Tags: docker, networking, virtualization

I need to connect two containers through a bridge but I need to set their interfaces name. How can I do that?

```
     docker network create --subnet 192.168.100.0/24 --driver bridge br0_nw
     docker network connect --ip 192.168.100.0 br0_nw cont1
     docker network connect --ip 192.168.100.0 br0_nw cont2
```

Is there any option like `interface-name`:

```
     docker network connect --ip 192.168.100.0 --interface-name ethx br0_nw cont1
```

Thanks

Comment: Might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750086/docker-compose-adding-identifier-to-network-name

Comment: Basically, docker creates veth ten tries to change its name to eth<count> based on the interfaces that docker knows about. But in my case, I connect a container to external ovs with eth1 which docker doesn't aware of. So it gives me this error `Error response from daemon: failed to add interface veth61751e9 to sandbox: error renaming interface "veth61751e9" to "eth1": file exists`