How to run a pgAdmin4 docker instance managing multiple postgres docker instances?
My project need to have a database (postgres) for the code itself and another database to have kong api gateway data stored.
I would like to have an instance of pgadmin4 managing both postgres servers.
For this, I created 2 compose files:
The one for the project that is working fine:

    services:
    db:
    image: postgres:16.3
    container_name: local_pgdb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - local_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
        - pg_Network
    pgadmin:
      container_name: PgAdmin4
      image: dpage/pgadmin4:8.7
      restart: always
      environment:
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    networks:
        - pg_Network
    rabbitmq:
      image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
      container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    restart: always
    environment:
      "RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE": "unique-erlang-cookie"
    ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672
    volumes:
        - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
        - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
    networks:
        - rabbitmq_go_net
    volumes:
        local_pgdata:
        pgadmin-data:
    networks:
        rabbitmq_go_net:
        driver: bridge
        pg_Network:
        driver: bridge

The one for kong API Gateway:
services:
      #######################################
      # Postgres: Kong Database
      #######################################
      kong-db:
        image: postgres:16.3
        container_name: kong-db
        ports:
          - "5433:5433"
        networks:
          - kong-net
        environment:
          POSTGRES_DB: kong
          POSTGRES_USER: kong
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: kong
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "kong"]
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 5s
          retries: 5
        restart: on-failure
      #######################################
      # Kong database migration
      #######################################
      kong-migrations:
        image: kong/kong-gateway:3.2.1.0
        command: kong migrations bootstrap
        container_name: kong-migrations
        networks:
          - kong-net
        depends_on:
          kong-db:
            condition: service_healthy
        environment:
          KONG_DATABASE: postgres
          KONG_PG_HOST: kong-db
          KONG_PG_DATABASE: kong
          KONG_PG_USER: kong
          KONG_PG_PASSWORD: kong
        restart: on-failure
      #######################################
      # Kong: The API Gateway
      #######################################
      kong-ce:
        image: kong/kong-gateway:3.2.1.0
        container_name: kong
        networks:
          - kong-net
        restart: on-failure
        depends_on:
            kong-db:
            condition: service_healthy
        environment:
            KONG_DATABASE: postgres
            KONG_PG_HOST: kong-db
            KONG_PG_DATABASE: kong
            KONG_PG_USER: kong
          KONG_PG_PASSWORD: kong
          KONG_PROXY_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8000, 0.0.0.0:8443 ssl
          KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
    
         # KONG_SSL: "on"
         # KONG_SSL_CERT: /certs/domain.crt
         # KONG_SSL_CERT_KEY: /certs/domain.key
         # KONG_LICENSE_DATA: 'Add License Key'
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://kong-ce:8001"]
          interval: 5s
          timeout: 2s
          retries: 10
    
        ports:
          - "8000-8001:8000-8001/tcp"
          - "8443:8443"
          - "8444:8444"
    
    volumes:
      pgadmin-data-Kong:
      ##    - ./certs:/certs
    networks:
      kong-net:
        external: true

My problem is to have PGAdmin4 connect to both postgres servers.
When I set a new server up, pgAdmin4 does not connect to it.I
To troubleshoot, I have inspected the container and got the correct ip adress: In vain
I have set everything on the same network: In vain.

Does anyone help me with this?
Any help would be really appreciated. Thank You in advance.


Your docker containers have to be in the same network. Your docker-compose.yaml automatically creates a network for all the services in it. Since you have two different compose files, you have two different networks. You could either create a manual network and add the two database containers as well as the pgadmin container (https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/network/). You could also try to add the network pg_Network to the kong-db service.

If the problem is related to network mismatch, the easiest setup is to just outright delete all of the networks: blocks in the entire file.  Compose will create a network named default and connect all of the containers to it.

Whatever I try I am getting an error message: Unable to connect to server: Connection timout expired. I properly changed the ipadress after having inspected the container. As far as my both files are on different projets, I see that the network name is prefixed by the name of the projet. pgAdmin4 is not on the same project than the 2nd postgres server.  Could that be a problem?

I will try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750086/docker-compose-adding-identifier-to-network-name and let you know.

Adding an alias like
pg_Network:
name: postgresNet
driver: bridge and pointing both DB to that network works fine.

I modified both compose files on my 2 projects with:
networks:
  pg_Network:
    name: postgresNet
    driver: bridge

I pointed both databases to this network alias. PGAdmin4 connects to both postgres servers.
Just as an information: I set
environment:
      PGPORT: 5433

to have the second postgres running on another port.
