# Unable to connect neo4j and elasticsearch in docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, neo4j, graphaware

I'm trying to connect neo4j to elasticsearch in docker container with the graphaware plugin and keep getting the same error :

```
ERROR Failed to create Elasticsearch index. org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9200 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Everything works well when I run ES and neo4j without any container.
Here is the total log of what happen when i run `docker compose up`:

```
Creating network "neo4jesdocker_neo-elk" with driver "bridge"
Creating elastic_container ... 
Creating neo4j ... 
Creating elastic_container
Creating neo4j ... done
Attaching to elastic_container, neo4j
elastic_container | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:22,827][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:23,023][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [8a-rsYj] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda6)]], net usable_space [486.2gb], net total_space [533.2gb], types [ext4]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:23,024][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [8a-rsYj] heap size [247.5mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:23,028][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [8a-rsYj] node name derived from node ID [8a-rsYjdR6Gh9liZ3H5oEQ]; set [node.name] to override
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:23,029][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [8a-rsYj] version[6.4.2], pid[1], build[default/tar/04711c2/2018-09-26T13:34:09.098244Z], OS[Linux/4.15.0-38-generic/amd64], JVM["Oracle Corporation"/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/10.0.2/10.0.2+13]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:23,029][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [8a-rsYj] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.nbXRlMe7, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -XX:UseAVX=2, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xmx256m, -Xms256m, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,006][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,006][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [analysis-common]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,006][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [ingest-common]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,006][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [lang-expression]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,007][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [lang-mustache]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,007][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [lang-painless]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,007][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [mapper-extras]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,007][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [parent-join]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,007][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [percolator]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,007][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [rank-eval]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,007][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [reindex]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [repository-url]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [transport-netty4]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [tribe]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [x-pack-core]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,009][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [x-pack-security]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,009][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,009][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [x-pack-upgrade]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,009][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,010][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:25,010][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [8a-rsYj] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:27,224][WARN ][o.e.d.s.ScriptModule     ] Script: returning default values for missing document values is deprecated. Set system property '-Des.scripting.exception_for_missing_value=true' to make behaviour compatible with future major versions.
neo4j          | Active database: graph.db
neo4j          | Directories in use:
neo4j          |   home:         /var/lib/neo4j
neo4j          |   config:       /var/lib/neo4j/conf
neo4j          |   logs:         /var/lib/neo4j/logs
neo4j          |   plugins:      /plugins
neo4j          |   import:       NOT SET
neo4j          |   data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
neo4j          |   certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
neo4j          |   run:          /var/lib/neo4j/run
neo4j          | Starting Neo4j.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:28.932+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.discovery_listen_address
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:28.936+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.raft_advertised_address
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:28.937+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.raft_listen_address
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:28.937+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: ha.host.coordination
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:28.937+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.transaction_advertised_address
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:28.937+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.discovery_advertised_address
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:28.937+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: ha.host.data
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:28.937+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: causal_clustering.transaction_listen_address
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:28.958+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.4.7 ========
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:29.020+0000 INFO  Starting...
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:30,366][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [8a-rsYj] parsed [0] roles from file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/roles.yml]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:31,261][INFO ][o.e.x.m.j.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [controller/92] [Main.cc@109] controller (64 bit): Version 6.4.2 (Build 660eefe6f2ea55) Copyright (c) 2018 Elasticsearch BV
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:32,118][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [8a-rsYj] using discovery type [zen]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:33,388][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [8a-rsYj] initialized
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:33,395][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [8a-rsYj] starting ...
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:33,653][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [8a-rsYj] publish_address {172.27.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:33,687][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [8a-rsYj] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.159+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.162+0000 INFO [c.g.r.b.RuntimeKernelExtension] GraphAware Runtime enabled, bootstrapping...
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.208+0000 INFO [c.g.r.b.RuntimeKernelExtension] Bootstrapping module with order 2, ID ES, using com.graphaware.module.es.ElasticSearchModuleBootstrapper
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.354+0000 INFO  ElasticSearch index-prefix set to neo4j-index
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.355+0000 INFO  ElasticSearch key-property set to uuid
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.355+0000 INFO  ElasticSearch force-strings set to false
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.358+0000 INFO  Elasticsearch URI set to localhost
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.358+0000 ERROR Elasticsearch protocol set to default protocol http
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.358+0000 INFO  Elasticsearch port set to 9200
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.359+0000 INFO  ElasticSearch index-prefix set to neo4j-index
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.359+0000 INFO  ElasticSearch key-property set to uuid
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.360+0000 INFO  ElasticSearch force-strings set to false
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.361+0000 INFO  Elasticsearch mapping configured with class com.graphaware.module.es.mapping.DefaultMapping
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.388+0000 INFO  Registering module ES with GraphAware Runtime.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:34.392+0000 INFO [c.g.r.b.RuntimeKernelExtension] GraphAware Runtime bootstrapped, starting the Runtime...
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:36,843][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [8a-rsYj] zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)[, ], reason: new_master {8a-rsYj}{8a-rsYjdR6Gh9liZ3H5oEQ}{hCd93BhoRCWIPTrONQxw0g}{172.27.0.2}{172.27.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=12476059648, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:36,849][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [8a-rsYj] new_master {8a-rsYj}{8a-rsYjdR6Gh9liZ3H5oEQ}{hCd93BhoRCWIPTrONQxw0g}{172.27.0.2}{172.27.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=12476059648, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {8a-rsYj}{8a-rsYjdR6Gh9liZ3H5oEQ}{hCd93BhoRCWIPTrONQxw0g}{172.27.0.2}{172.27.0.2:9300}{ml.machine_memory=12476059648, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true} committed version [1] source [zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)[, ]]])
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:36,879][INFO ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [8a-rsYj] publish_address {172.27.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:36,883][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [8a-rsYj] started
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:37,504][WARN ][o.e.x.s.a.s.m.NativeRoleMappingStore] [8a-rsYj] Failed to clear cache for realms [[]]
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:37,629][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [8a-rsYj] license [39ad9926-bc4e-420d-bf69-bc14ad5751a5] mode [basic] - valid
elastic_container | [2018-11-10T17:28:37,652][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [8a-rsYj] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.056+0000 INFO  Starting GraphAware...
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.058+0000 INFO  Loading module metadata...
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.059+0000 INFO  Loading metadata for module ES
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.132+0000 INFO  Module ES seems to have been registered before, metadata loaded successfully.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.133+0000 INFO  Module ES has not changed configuration since last run, already initialized.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.183+0000 INFO  Module metadata loaded.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.184+0000 INFO  Starting transaction-driven modules...
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.184+0000 INFO  Starting Elasticsearch Writer...
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.207+0000 INFO  Creating Jest Client...
neo4j          | SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
neo4j          | SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
neo4j          | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.257+0000 INFO  Created Jest Client.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.285+0000 ERROR Failed to create Elasticsearch index. org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9200 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
neo4j          | java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9200 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.module.es.mapping.BaseMapping.lambda$createIndexAndMapping$0(BaseMapping.java:185)
neo4j          |    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
neo4j          |    at java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1$2.accept(DistinctOps.java:175)
neo4j          |    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
neo4j          |    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
neo4j          |    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
neo4j          |    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
neo4j          |    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
neo4j          |    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
neo4j          |    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.module.es.mapping.BaseMapping.createIndexAndMapping(BaseMapping.java:181)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.module.es.ElasticSearchWriter.createIndexIfNotExist(ElasticSearchWriter.java:220)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.module.es.ElasticSearchWriter.start(ElasticSearchWriter.java:92)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.runtime.module.thirdparty.WriterBasedThirdPartyIntegrationModule.start(WriterBasedThirdPartyIntegrationModule.java:61)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.module.es.ElasticSearchModule.start(ElasticSearchModule.java:87)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.runtime.manager.ProductionTxDrivenModuleManager.start(ProductionTxDrivenModuleManager.java:49)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.runtime.manager.BaseTxDrivenModuleManager.startModules(BaseTxDrivenModuleManager.java:113)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.runtime.TxDrivenRuntime.startModules(TxDrivenRuntime.java:147)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.runtime.ProductionRuntime.startModules(ProductionRuntime.java:70)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.runtime.BaseGraphAwareRuntime.start(BaseGraphAwareRuntime.java:134)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.runtime.bootstrap.RuntimeKernelExtension.lambda$start$0(RuntimeKernelExtension.java:117)
neo4j          |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
neo4j          | Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9200 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
neo4j          |    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
neo4j          |    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
neo4j          |    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
neo4j          |    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
neo4j          |    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
neo4j          |    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
neo4j          |    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
neo4j          |    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
neo4j          |    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
neo4j          |    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
neo4j          |    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:47)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.module.es.mapping.BaseMapping.createIndexAndMapping(BaseMapping.java:199)
neo4j          |    at com.graphaware.module.es.mapping.BaseMapping.lambda$createIndexAndMapping$0(BaseMapping.java:183)
neo4j          |    ... 21 more
neo4j          | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
neo4j          |    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
neo4j          |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
neo4j          |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
neo4j          |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
neo4j          |    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
neo4j          |    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
neo4j          |    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
neo4j          |    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
neo4j          |    ... 33 more
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.288+0000 INFO  Started Elasticsearch Writer.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.289+0000 INFO  Transaction-driven modules started.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.289+0000 INFO  There are no timer-driven runtime modules. Not scheduling any tasks.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.290+0000 INFO  GraphAware started.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:42.291+0000 INFO [c.g.r.b.RuntimeKernelExtension] GraphAware Runtime automatically started.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:45.022+0000 INFO  Started.
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:45.114+0000 INFO [c.g.s.f.b.GraphAwareServerBootstrapper] started
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:45.115+0000 INFO  Mounted unmanaged extension [com.graphaware.server] at [/graphaware]
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:45.296+0000 INFO  Google Analytics enabled
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:45.305+0000 INFO  Mounting GraphAware Framework at /graphaware
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:45.312+0000 INFO  Will try to scan the following packages: {com.**.graphaware.**,org.**.graphaware.**,net.**.graphaware.**}
neo4j          | 2018-11-10 17:28:47.382+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
```

I have created the folders for the docker volumes with the following bash file :

```
 #!/bin/bash
mkdir -p elasticsearch/config elasticsearch/data
mkdir -p neo4j/conf neo4j/data neo4j/plugins neo4j/logs
cp ../docker-utilities/apoc-3.4.0.3-all.jar neo4j/plugins/
cp ../docker-utilities/graphaware-neo4j-to-elasticsearch-3.4.9.52.11.jar neo4j/plugins/
cp ../docker-utilities/graphaware-server-community-all-3.4.9.52.jar neo4j/plugins/
cp ../docker-utilities/neo4j.confmini neo4j/conf/neo4j.conf
cp ../docker-utilities/elasticsearch.yml elasticsearch/config/
```

This bash file put in the right places the required plugins and two conf files :
elasticsearch.yml :

```
cluster.name: test_cluster
node.name: "node"



############################## Network And HTTP ###############################

# Elasticsearch, by default, binds itself to the 0.0.0.0 address, and listens
# on port [9200-9300] for HTTP traffic and on port [9300-9400] for node-to-node
# communication. (the range means that if the port is busy, it will automatically
# try the next port).

# Set the bind address specifically (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.bind_host: 192.168.0.1

# Set the address other nodes will use to communicate with this node. If not
# set, it is automatically derived. It must point to an actual IP address.
#
#network.publish_host: 192.168.0.1

# Set both 'bind_host' and 'publish_host':
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1

# Set a custom port for the node to node communication (9300 by default):
#
#transport.tcp.port: 9300

# Enable compression for all communication between nodes (disabled by default):
#
#transport.tcp.compress: true

# Set a custom port to listen for HTTP traffic:
#
#http.port: 9200

# Set a custom allowed content length:
#
#http.max_content_length: 100mb

# Disable HTTP completely:
#
#http.enabled: false

http.host: 0.0.0.0
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length, X-User"
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

and neo4j.conf:

```
ACCEPT.LICENSE.AGREEMENT=yes
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=com.graphaware.server=/graphaware
com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true



com.graphaware.module.UIDM.initializeUntil=0

#ES becomes the module ID:
com.graphaware.module.ES.2=com.graphaware.module.es.ElasticSearchModuleBootstrapper

#URI of Elasticsearch
com.graphaware.module.ES.uri=localhost

#Port of Elasticsearch
com.graphaware.module.ES.port=9200
```

Finally the docker compose to link all that :

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  neo4jESdock:
    restart: always
    image: neo4j:3.4.7
    container_name: neo4j
    environment:
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_AUTH=none
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7474
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6477
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7687
      - elastic="http://elastic_container"
    volumes:
      - ./neo4j/data:/data
      - ./neo4j/plugins:/plugins
      - ./neo4j/conf:/conf
      - ./neo4j/logs:/neologs
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 6477:6477
      - 7687:7687
    networks:
      - neo-elk
  elastic:
    image: elasticsearch:6.4.2
    restart: always
    container_name: elastic_container
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/etc/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      - neo4j="http://neo4j"
    networks:
      - neo-elk
networks:
  neo-elk:
    driver: bridge
```

And some documentation on similar projects :
https://github.com/graphaware/graph-aided-search-demo
[Connect docker-compose files by shared network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101748/connect-docker-compose-files-by-shared-network)
https://github.com/mitdbg/aurum-datadiscovery

I'm not very experienced with docker...

Comment: There is a mistake in ES volumes, proper path to config is :
- ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that neo4j tries to connect to elasticsearch on localhost, whereas the elasticsearch container is on a different ip.

According to https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ you can use the name of the service, so instead of localhost you can put elastic.

Comment: Hello,
I've been banging my head on this all day thank you...
Indeed, I don't know what docker does with ips but I changed one line in the neo4j.conf file :
com.graphaware.module.ES.uri=elastic
And it works.
TY !

Comment: I know the feeling :). Glad to be of help