# Filebeat does not send logs to logstash

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, elastic-stack, filebeat

So here's the big picture: **my objective is to index large amounts of (.txt) data using the ELK stack + filebeat.**

Basically, my problem is that filebeat seems to be unable to send logs to logstash. My guess is, some docker networking config is off...

The code for my project is available at https://github.com/mhyousefi/elk-docker.

#### **THE ELK CONTAINER**

To do so, I have one `docker-compose.yml` to run a container from the image [`sebp/elk`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjZw62UxOzcAhUjOpoKHa5NDrgQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhub.docker.com%2Fr%2Fsebp%2Felk%2F&usg=AOvVaw3Ta4fdzI2n_K4Ws4jO4HD7), which looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  elk:
    container_name: elk
    image: sebp/elk
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
      - "9200:9200"
      - "5045:5044"
    volumes:
      - /path/to/volumed-folder:/logstash
    networks:
      - elk_net

networks:
  elk_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Once the container is created, I go to the container bash terminal and run the command:

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash --path.data /tmp/logstash/data -f /logstash/config/filebeat-config.conf
```

Running this command, I get the following logs and it will then just start waiting without printing any further logs:

```
$ /opt/logstash/bin/logstash --path.data /tmp/logstash/data -f /logstash/config/filebeat-config.conf                                                                                             
Sending Logstash's logs to /opt/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-08-14T11:51:11,693][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/tmp/logstash/data/queue"}
[2018-08-14T11:51:11,701][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/tmp/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
[2018-08-14T11:51:12,194][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2018-08-14T11:51:12,410][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"3646b6e4-d540-4c9c-a38d-2769aef5a05e", :path=>"/tmp/logstash/data/uuid"}
[2018-08-14T11:51:13,089][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.3.2"}
[2018-08-14T11:51:15,554][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>6, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-08-14T11:51:16,088][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2018-08-14T11:51:16,101][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2018-08-14T11:51:16,291][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2018-08-14T11:51:16,391][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[2018-08-14T11:51:16,398][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[2018-08-14T11:51:16,460][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2018-08-14T11:51:16,515][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2018-08-14T11:51:16,559][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2018-08-14T11:51:16,688][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Installing elasticsearch template to _template/logstash
[2018-08-14T11:51:16,899][INFO ][logstash.inputs.beats    ] Beats inputs: Starting input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5045"}
[2018-08-14T11:51:16,925][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x54ab986e run>"}
[2018-08-14T11:51:17,170][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.Server] Starting server on port: 5045
[2018-08-14T11:51:17,187][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2018-08-14T11:51:17,637][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9601}
```

Now, this is what the `filebeat-config.conf` looks like:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5044"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}"
  }
}
```

#### **THE FILEBEAT CONTAINER**

My `filebeat` container is created using the bellow `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  filebeat:
    container_name: filebeat
    hostname: filebeat
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.3.0
    user: root
    # command: ./filebeat -c /usr/share/filebeat-volume/config/filebeat.yml -E name=mybeat
    volumes:
      # "volumed-folder" lies under ${PROJECT_DIR}/filebeat or could be anywhere else you wish
      - /path/to/volumed-folder:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat-volume:ro
    networks:
      - filebeat_net

networks:
  filebeat_net:
    external: true
```

Once the container is created, I go to the container bash terminal, replace the existing `filebeat.yml` under `/usr/share/filebeat` with the one I have volumed, and run the command:

```
./filebeat -e -c ./filebeat.yml -E name="mybeat"
```

The terminal immediately displays the following logs:

```
root@filebeat filebeat]# ./filebeat -e -c ./filebeat.yml -E name="mybeat"
2018-08-14T12:13:16.325Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:492    Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Data path: [/usr/share/filebeat/data] Logs path: [/usr/share/filebeat/logs]
2018-08-14T12:13:16.325Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:499    Beat UUID: 3b4b3897-ef77-43ad-b982-89e8f690a96e
2018-08-14T12:13:16.325Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:716    Beat info       {"system_info": {"beat": {"path": {"config": "/usr/share/filebeat", "data": "/usr/share/filebeat/data", "home": "/usr/share/filebeat", "logs": "/usr/share/filebeat/logs"}, "type": "filebeat", "uuid": "3b4b3897-ef77-43ad-b982-89e8f690a96e"}}}
2018-08-14T12:13:16.325Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:725    Build info      {"system_info": {"build": {"commit": "a04cb664d5fbd4b1aab485d1766f3979c138fd38", "libbeat": "6.3.0", "time": "2018-06-11T22:34:44.000Z", "version": "6.3.0"}}}
2018-08-14T12:13:16.325Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:728    Go runtime info {"system_info": {"go": {"os":"linux","arch":"amd64","max_procs":6,"version":"go1.9.4"}}}
2018-08-14T12:13:16.327Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:732    Host info       {"system_info": {"host": {"architecture":"x86_64","boot_time":"2018-08-04T17:34:15Z","containerized":true,"hostname":"filebeat","ips":["127.0.0.1/8","172.28.0.2/16"],"kernel_version":"4.4.0-116-generic","mac_addresses":["02:42:ac:1c:00:02"],"os":{"family":"redhat","platform":"centos","name":"CentOS Linux","version":"7 (Core)","major":7,"minor":5,"patch":1804,"codename":"Core"},"timezone":"UTC","timezone_offset_sec":0}}}
2018-08-14T12:13:16.328Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:761    Process info    {"system_info": {"process": {"capabilities": {"inheritable":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"permitted":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"effective":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"bounding":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"ambient":null}, "cwd": "/usr/share/filebeat", "exe": "/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat", "name": "filebeat", "pid": 93, "ppid": 28, "seccomp": {"mode":"filter"}, "start_time": "2018-08-14T12:13:15.530Z"}}}
2018-08-14T12:13:16.328Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:225    Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 6.3.0
2018-08-14T12:13:16.329Z        INFO    pipeline/module.go:81   Beat name: mybeat
2018-08-14T12:13:16.329Z        WARN    [cfgwarn]       beater/filebeat.go:61   DEPRECATED: prospectors are deprecated, Use `inputs` instead. Will be removed in version: 7.0.0
2018-08-14T12:13:16.330Z        INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:97   Starting metrics logging every 30s
2018-08-14T12:13:16.330Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:315    filebeat start running.
2018-08-14T12:13:16.330Z        INFO    registrar/registrar.go:112      Loading registrar data from /usr/share/filebeat/data/registry
2018-08-14T12:13:16.330Z        INFO    registrar/registrar.go:123      States Loaded from registrar: 0
2018-08-14T12:13:16.331Z        WARN    beater/filebeat.go:354  Filebeat is unable to load the Ingest Node pipelines for the configured modules because the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled. If you have already loaded the Ingest Node pipelines or are using Logstash pipelines, you can ignore this warning.
2018-08-14T12:13:16.331Z        INFO    crawler/crawler.go:48   Loading Inputs: 1
2018-08-14T12:13:16.331Z        INFO    log/input.go:111        Configured paths: [/usr/share/filebeat-volume/data/Shakespeare.txt]
2018-08-14T12:13:16.331Z        INFO    input/input.go:87       Starting input of type: log; ID: 1899165251698784346 
2018-08-14T12:13:16.331Z        INFO    crawler/crawler.go:82   Loading and starting Inputs completed. Enabled inputs: 1
```

And the every 30 seconds, it displays the following:

```
2018-08-14T12:13:46.334Z        INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:124  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":20,"time":{"ms":24}},"total":{"ticks":30,"time":{"ms":36},"value":30},"user":{"ticks":10,"time":{"ms":12}}},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"16c484f0-0cf8-4c10-838d-b39755284af9","uptime":{"ms":30017}},"memstats":{"gc_next":4473924,"memory_alloc":3040104,"memory_total":3040104,"rss":21061632}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"output":{"type":"logstash"},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":0}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":6},"load":{"1":1.46,"15":1.52,"5":1.66,"norm":{"1":0.2433,"15":0.2533,"5":0.2767}}}}}}
```

And no index-patterns are created in Kibana.

This is what my `filebeat.yml` looks like:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /path/to/a/log/file

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["elk:5044"]

setup.kibana:
  host: "localhost:5601"
```

I have used [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects) to define the `networks` section of my `docker-compose` files, so that my containers can talk to each other using their `container_name`s.

So, when I do

```
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["elk:5044"]
```

I expect filebeat to send logs to port 5044 of the elk container, where logstash is listening for incoming messages.

After I run filebeat inside its terminal, I actually do see the following logs in the terminal in which I did `docker-compose up elk`:

```
elk    | 
elk    | ==> /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log <==
elk    | [2018-08-14T11:51:16,974][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataIndexTemplateService] [fZr_LDR] adding template [logstash] for index patterns [logstash-*]
```

which I am assuming some sort of communication has been made between logstash and filebeat.

However, on the other hand, despite following the mentioned stackoverflow response, I cannot do `ping elk` in my filebeat container. The hostname is not resolved.

I appreciate any help!

**UPDATE (Aug 15, 2018)**

I think I don't even need to open a port for my `ELK` container. What happens is that `Logstash` is listening on port 5044 inside the container. As long as the `filebeat.yml` file inside the`Filebeat` container can resolve the `ELK` host and then send its logs over to 5044 port there ("elk:5044"), they should all work fine.

That's why I deleted the `"5045:5044"` line, and fixed the `networks` section inside the `docker-compose.yml` file for my `Filebeat`container to include the following:

```
networks:
  filebeat_net:
    external:
      name: elk_elk_net
```

And it seems to work, since when I do `ping elk`, I am getting a connection.

**While the networking issue is resolved (I can ping!), the connection between `Logstash` and `Filebeat` remains troublesome, and keep getting the following message every 30 seconds.**

```
2018-08-14T12:13:46.334Z        INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:124  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":20,"time":{"ms":24}},"total":{"ticks":30,"time":{"ms":36},"value":30},"user":{"ticks":10,"time":{"ms":12}}},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"16c484f0-0cf8-4c10-838d-b39755284af9","uptime":{"ms":30017}},"memstats":{"gc_next":4473924,"memory_alloc":3040104,"memory_total":3040104,"rss":21061632}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"output":{"type":"logstash"},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":0}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":6},"load":{"1":1.46,"15":1.52,"5":1.66,"norm":{"1":0.2433,"15":0.2533,"5":0.2767}}}}}}
```

In the terminal of my filebeat container, I am also getting the following logs periodically when running the filebeat command in verbose mode:

```
2018-08-15T16:26:41.986Z        DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:124      Run input
2018-08-15T16:26:41.986Z        DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:147        Start next scan
2018-08-15T16:26:41.986Z        DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:168        input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve my problem. First, the issue with container connection was resolved as mentioned in the **UPDATE (Aug 15, 2018)** section of my question.

The problem with `Filebeat` not sending logs over to `Logstash` was due to the fact that I had not explicitly specified my input/output configurations to be enabled (which is a frustrating fact to me since it is not clearly mentioned in the docs). So, changing my `filebeat.yml` file the following fixed did the trick.

```yaml
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - ${PWD}/filebeat-volume/data/*.txt

output.logstash:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["elk:5044"]
  index: "your cusotm index"

setup.kibana:
  host: "elk:5601"
```

Answer (score 1):

Networking in namespaced in containers by default, which means each container gets it's own private ip, and localhost in a container is local to just that container.

That means you need to specify the DNS entry of the elastic server, not localhost in your config file. With compose and swarm mode, the service name is automatically setup with a DNS entry pointing to your containers:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5044"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "elk:9200" ]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}"
  }
}
```

This also requires that you share a common network between the containers. You get this by default when creating everything in the same compose file. When you have multiple stacks/projects being deployed, you'll need to define a common external network in at least one file. Since I can't tell your elk project name to know the full network name, here is the change you can make to elk to connect it to filebeat_net instead:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  elk:
    container_name: elk
    image: sebp/elk
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
      - "9200:9200"
      - "5045:5044"
    volumes:
      - /path/to/volumed-folder:/logstash
    networks:
      - elk_net
      - filebeat_net

networks:
  elk_net:
    driver: bridge
  filebeat_net:
    external: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to resolve the networking issue as mentioned in my update section.

Comment: As for your first point, I think that `localhost` will do because both `Logstash` and `Elasticsearch` are in the same container here. In fact, if I run a different logstash.conf (for example to index the content of a file instead of filebeat input) it works and everything is perfectly fine in `Kibana`.

Comment: @mhyousefi It's not clear if you still have a problem. If so, make sure to specify what isn't working in your update. And if not, you should check an answer so that the question does not remain open. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my problem is now specified clearly in my update.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but what happened to me was that my port was not being exposed to the application outside the container. 
What I did was just to expose the port for the other applications. 
I did it at the time I was installing the docker with the option -p 5044, 5044 is the port which is going to listen the requests.

```
docker run -d --name logstash 
-p 5044:5044
--restart=always 
-e "XPACK.MONITORING.ELASTICSEARCH.URL=http://ELASTIC_IP:9200" 
docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.0.0
```