# Link containers that are configured in two different docker-compose files

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose, devops

Let's say i have two different `docker-compose` configurations:

`db.yml`:

```
version: '3'
networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: backend

volumes:
    mongo_data:

services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongodb
        container_name: mongodb
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        networks:
            - backend
        volumes:
            - mongo_data:/data/db
```

`admin.yml`:

```
version: '3'
networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: backend

volumes:
    mongo_data:

services:
    mongoclient:
        image: mongoclient/mongoclient
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        networks:
            - backend
        depends_on:
            - mongodb
        links:
            - mongodb
```

This won't work, because the linked container is not configured in the same file. But is there a way to achieve something similar?

I'd like to have a cleaner setup for setting up my production environment so that i am able to restart only the relevant bits that changed and not everything at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects)

Comment: The containers are already in the same network and should be able to communicate. What exaclty are you trying to achieve? (startup order or connection) And is the backend network already present?

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link to mongodb you need to link "external":

```
...
external_links:
        - project_mongodb_1:mongodb
...
```

Mind that you need to replace `project_mongodb_1` with the correct name that `docker-compose ps` gives you. You need to remove the `depends_on` section. This won't work. See here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3951

However you shouldn't use links at all because they are deprecated. See here for more info: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external_links

See this on how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38089080/1029251