# Docker DNS with Multiple Projects Using the Same Network

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    frontend:
        image: alpine
        command: tail -f /dev/null
        networks:
            - shared
            - default
    backend:
        image: alpine
        command: tail -f /dev/null
        networks:
            - shared
            - default
networks:
    shared:
        external: true
```

Based on the file from above I create two projects which use the same network (`shared`) and the same service names (`frontend` and `backend`):

```
docker-compose -p foo up -d
docker-compose -p bar up -d
```

Does the DNS of docker make sure that `docker-compose -p foo exec frontend ping backend` only resolves to the backend container in project `foo` and vice versa for project `bar`?

Comment: Which Docker Compose version?

Comment: Relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38088279/10975585).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4645, the resolve order in this case in non deterministic. Since the network is being converted to unordered dict in golang, the order is not preserved. Which implies https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/blob/master/sandbox.go#L593 the order of endpoints being queried don't match the order of network.

The solution is to define https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#priority if using docker-compose version 2. Or fully qualified dns name as `service.network` such as `backend.foo_default` or `backend.shared`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your setup I have used `nslookup` to find out whether the DNS resolution is isolated or not.

```
$ docker-compose -p foo exec frontend nslookup backend

Name:      backend
Address 1: 172.19.0.2 foo_backend_1.shared
Address 2: 172.19.0.4 bar_backend_1.shared
```

As you can see from the output above, `backend` **resolves to both of the containers**.

Comment: If assign a local network to both services. It seems that it only resolve to the local network service. I am not sure it’s the order of the network is important or not.

Comment: @prd Was the description (i.e. `docker-compose.yml` file) different, when you wrote your answer? `nslookup` only finds the service of the `backend` of the network `default` on my Mac (`docker-compose version 1.29.2`) following the current description of the question and your answer. Maybe something changed in the newer Docker Compose version.

Comment: @maiermic I guess something with Docker's name resolution must have changed. I could verify that the same setup does not work as described in my answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48024244/10975585) might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you use docker swarm you can qualify hostnames with the service name to disambiguate containers. But I don't believe docker-compose does this.

Comment: Just tried, docker-compose support service.network to disambiguate.

Comment: That's useful. Docker swarm does both I think. I guess depends if you'd rather be coupled to the service or the network.