# Docker compose service name conflict with external network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am trying to connect two locally developed projects running on docker-compose by using [external networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1).

From one side I have an 1st application intended to be exposed. Compose contains hosts: `app` and `rabbit`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    # ...
  rabbit:
    # ...

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

From other side I have second application expected to see 1st application:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    # ...
    networks:
      - paymentservice_default
      - default

networks:
  paymentservice_default:
    external: true
```

Reaching host `rabbit.paymentservice_default` is possible.

However service `app` (1st) conflicts with `app` (2nd):

```
root@6db86687229c:/app# ping app.paymentservice_default
PING app.paymentservice_default (192.168.80.6) 56(84) bytes of data.

root@6db86687229c:/app# ping app
PING app (192.168.80.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

In general from 2nd compose perspective hosts `app` and `app.paymentservice_default` shares same IP making `app.paymentservice_default` undiscoverable.

The question here is, do I have proper configuration and conflict **can be avoided without changing service names `app`**? Why this constraint? Taking consideration that every docker-compose configuration is shared across projects and can be developed in micro-services world.

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf583a
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you specify any `networks:`, the `app` container won't be attached to its own Compose file's `default` network; you need to explicitly list it.  I can't tell if that will help your issue though.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'll update question. However, this network is not a problem.

Comment: try to add `-p project_name` when you run `docker-compose up`

Comment: Better to go for swarm services ( if not K8s )

Comment: Have you tried [alias](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#aliases) yet?

Comment: @rok I'm using `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`, same purpose, works as cited (see network name). @Soumen - that's another topic, question is compose-related.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker DNS with Multiple Projects Using the Same Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506950/docker-dns-with-multiple-projects-using-the-same-network)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following configuration on [Docker Playground](https://labs.play-with-docker.com)

**paymentservice.docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    image: busybox
    # keep container running
    command: tail -f /dev/null
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

**other.docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    image: busybox
    # keep container running
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    networks:
      - paymentservice_default
      - default

networks:
  paymentservice_default:
    external: true
```

Run both projects

```sh
$ COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=paymentservice docker-compose -f paymentservice.docker-compose.yml up -d
$ COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=other docker-compose -f other.docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Show Docker IPs

```
$ docker ps -q | xargs -n 1 docker inspect --format '{{ .Name }} {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}} {{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' | sed 's#^/##';
```

I got

```
other_app_1  172.20.0.2 172.19.0.4
paymentservice_app_1  172.19.0.3
paymentservice_rabbit_1  172.19.0.2
```

and I pinged `paymentservice_app_1` (172.19.0.3) from `other_app_1` using `app.paymentservice_default`

```
$ docker exec -it other_app_1 ping -c 1 app.paymentservice_default
PING app.paymentservice_default (172.19.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.258 ms

--- app.paymentservice_default ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.258/0.258/0.258 ms
```

and I pinged `other_app_1` (172.20.0.2) from `other_app_1` using `app`

```
$ docker exec -it other_app_1 ping -c 1 app
PING app (172.20.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.20.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms

--- app ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.054/0.054/0.054 ms
```

As you can see, I can access the 1st app (of `paymentservice.docker-compose.yml`) from the 2nd app (of `other.docker-compose.yml`).

The same works in the other direction. I pinged `other_app_1` (172.19.0.4) from `paymentservice_app_1` using `app.paymentservice_default`

```
$ docker exec -it paymentservice_app_1 ping -c 1 app.paymentservice_default
PING app.paymentservice_default (172.19.0.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.4: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.198 ms

--- app.paymentservice_default ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.198/0.198/0.198 ms
```

I pinged `paymentservice_app_1` (172.19.0.3) from `paymentservice_app_1` using `app`

```
$ docker exec -it paymentservice_app_1 ping -c 1 app
PING app (172.19.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms

--- app ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.057/0.057/0.057 ms
```

---

As you can see, I can access `app` service of both projects. If I like to access the service of the same project, I use the default network of the project. If I'd like to access the service of another project, I use the external network shared between both projects.

> **Note:** I would recommend to make this more explicit by creating the shared network outside of the projects using the command line
>
> ```
> docker network create shared-between-paymentservice-and-other
> ```
>
> and declaring it as external in both projects.

> **Note:** There is still the limitation that service discovery may not work if you have 3 projects with the same service name (e.g. `app`) in the same (external) network (sort of a namespace). In that case, it might be a better idea to rename your services, use multiple external networks, define [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#aliases) or use a totally different approach to discover/identify the Docker containers.

---

### Afterword

Has that been the requirement? I tried to reproduce your issue, but I'm not sure if I did the same as you. For example, I'm not sure, where you are running `ping`. Is `root@6db86687229c` the Docker host or a Docker container? Which container? I assumed it is the Docker container of service `app` of `other.docker-compose.yml`. Please comment if I'm missing something or misinterpreted your question and I will update my answer. Then I may explain in more detail or make another suggestion how to do service discovery between multiple Docker Compose projects.

---

### Appendix

#### Cleanup

```
$ COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=other docker-compose -f other.docker-compose.yml down
$ COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=paymentservice docker-compose -f paymentservice.docker-compose.yml down
```

#### Versions

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.0, build 7287ab3
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.26.0, build unknown
```