# Localstack SNS: Unable to send message to ElasticMq

Tags: localstack

I have 2 applications:

1 application uses `ElasticMq` queue for listening to the messages.
The 2nd application publishes the messages on an `SNS` topic.

I am able to subscribe to the `ElasticMq` queue on the `SNS` topic. But when I publish on the topic `local stack` is unable to send the message to `elasticmq` eventhough subscription was successful.

```
awslocal sns list-subscriptions-by-topic --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:classification-details-topic
{
    "Subscriptions": [
        {
            "SubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:classification-details-topic:ea470c5a-c352-472e-9ae0-a1386044b750",
            "Owner": "",
            "Protocol": "sqs",
            "Endpoint": "http://elasticmq-service:9324/queue/test",
            "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:classification-details-topic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the error message I receive:

> awslocal sns publish --topic-arn
>   arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:classification-details-topic
>   --message "My message"
>
> An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Publish
>   operation: An error occurred (AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue)
>   when calling the SendMessage operation:
>   AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue; see the SQS docs.

Am I wrong in having `elasticmq` subscribed on local stack?

I am running localstack using docker-compose file

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "4567-4584:4567-4584"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8001}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=${SERVICES- }
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR- }
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my_network
```

I have the elasticmq and other services as a part of different docker-compose using the same docker network "my_network"

The below is the complete docker-compose. I tried reproducing it by combining the entries into one docker-compose file.

**Steps to reproduce**

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticmq:
    build: ./elasticmq
    ports:
      - '9324:9324'
    networks:
      - my_network
    dns:
      - 172.16.198.101
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "4567-4584:4567-4584"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8001}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=${SERVICES- }
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR- }
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    links:
      - elasticmq:elasticmq-service
    networks:
      - my_network
    dns:
      - 172.16.198.101
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.198.0/24
```

After this one can run the following set of commands

```
awslocal sqs create-queue --queue-name test --endpoint http://elasticmq:9324/

awslocal sns create-topic --name test-topic

awslocal sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:test-topic --protocol sqs --notification-endpoin http://elasticmq-service:9324/queue/test
```

Comment: Could you post how you are starting `LocalStack`? Also out of curiosity is there a particular reason you are not using `SQS` from within `LocalStack`?

Comment: I running localstack using the docker-compose.yml. The reason of not using SQS is that application-1 is legacy, has implementation for elasticmq. I am developing a micro-service and I would want to avoid infrastructure changes for this micro-service.

Comment: How do you start `elasticmq`? Do you start it separately?

Comment: Yes I start the elasticmq first using the other docker-compose file

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I would hazard a guess that the networks of your 2 `docker-compose` files are not setup correctly.

For simplicity's sake I would merge the `elasticmq` service in the above `docker-compose` and try again (if you post your second `docker-compose` and exact `aws` command to create the subscription someone can try it locally).

If you really want to keep 2 separate `docker-compose` files then if the above works then at least you can pin point your problem. I'm afraid I am not too familiar with setting this up but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects) might help.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the additional details. I have a simplified version of a `docker-compose` that works for me. First of all [according to this](https://kevinholditch.co.uk/2017/10/19/running-sns-sqs-locally-in-docker-containers-supporting-fan-out/) you will need to create a config file to set the hostname of your `elasticmq` instance since it will not pick up the `container_name` from  `docker-compose` (similar to the `HOSTNAME` environment variable in `LocalStack` which I set below as you will see). The contents of this file named `elasticmq.conf` (in a folder named `config`) are:

```
include classpath("application.conf")

node-address {
  host = elasticmq
}

queues {
  test-queue {}
}
```

With that in place, the following `docker-compose` publishes the message without any errors:

```
version: '3'

services:

  elasticmq:
    image: s12v/elasticmq
    container_name: elasticmq
    ports:
      - '9324:9324'
    volumes:
      - ./config/elasticmq.conf:/etc/elasticmq/elasticmq.conf

  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    container_name: localstack
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sns
      - DEBUG=1
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - HOSTNAME=localstack
    ports:
      - "4575:4575"
      - "8080:8080"

  awscli:
    image: garland/aws-cli-docker
    container_name: awscli
    depends_on:
      - localstack
      - elasticmq
    environment:
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
          sleep 20
          aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4575 sns create-topic --name test_topic
          aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4575 sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:123456789012:test_topic --protocol http --notification-endpoint http://elasticmq:9324/queue/test-queue
          aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4575 sns publish --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:123456789012:test_topic --message "My message"
```

And the output:

[image]

Admittedly at this point I did not check `elasticmq` to see if the message got consumed but I leave that to you.