# How to get redis address from docker compose?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I'm trying to pass redis url to docker container but so far i couldn't get it to work. I did a little research and none of the answers worked for me.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  redis:
    image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    expose:
      - 6379
    links:
      - api
  api:
    image: tufanmeric/api:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - proxy
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
    deploy:
      mode: global
      labels:
        - 'traefik.port=3002'
        - 'traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/'
        - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.example.com'
        - 'traefik.docker.network=proxy'

networks:
  proxy:
```

> Error: Redis connection to redis failed - connect ENOENT redis

Comment: Have you tried to use `ports: - '6379:6379'` instead of `expose`?

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects)

Answer (score 4):

You can only communicate between containers on the same Docker network.  Docker Compose creates a `default` network for you, and absent any specific declaration your `redis` container is on that network.  But you also declare a separate `proxy` network, and only attach the `api` container to that other network.

The single simplest solution to this is to delete all of the `network:` blocks everywhere and just use the `default` network Docker Compose creates for you.  You may need to format the `REDIS_URL` variable as an actual URL, maybe like `redis://redis:6379`.

If you have a non-technical requirement to have separate networks, add `- default` to the networks listing for the `api` container.

You have a number of other settings in your `docker-compose.yml` that aren't especially useful.  `expose:` does almost nothing at all, and is usually also provided in a Dockerfile.  `links:` is an outdated way to make cross-container calls, and as you've declared it to make calls *from* Redis *to* your API server.  `hostname:` has no effect outside the container itself and is usually totally unnecessary.  `container_name:` does have some visible effects, but usually the container name Docker Compose picks is just fine.

This would leave you with:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  redis:
    image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
  api:
    image: tufanmeric/api:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
    depends_on:
      - redis
    deploy:
      mode: global
      labels:
        - 'traefik.port=3002'
        - 'traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/'
        - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.example.com'
        - 'traefik.docker.network=default'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I tried adding `- default` to the networks but now i can't access to the api endpoint, my docker runs on swarm mode, how can I make things work together?

Comment: @TufanMeri&amp;#231;UYGUNER If you declare more than one network on a traefik service then you need to specify the correct network name in a label so traefik can reach it. Sorry, can't remember the full label name.