# Connecting dockerized apps network to do api call

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a bit of a problem with connecting the dots.

I managed to dockerized our legacy app and our newer app, but now I need to make them to `talk` to one another via API call.

Projects:

- Project1 = using `project1_appnet` (bridge driver)
- Project2 = using `project2_appnet` (bridge driver)
- Project3 = using `project3_appnet` (bridge driver)

On my local, I have these 3 projects on 3 separates folders. Each project will have their own `app`, `db` and `cache` services.

This is the `docker-compose.yml` for one of the project. (They have nearly all the same docker-compose.yml only with different image and volume path)

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: ./docker/app
    image: 'cms/app:latest'
    networks:
      - appnet
    volumes:
      - './:/var/www/html:cached'
    ports:
      - '${APP_PORT}:80'
    working_dir: /var/www/html
  cache:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    networks:
      - appnet
    volumes:
      - 'cachedata:/data'
  db:
    image: 'mysql:5.7'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
      MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USER}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT}:3306'
    networks:
      - appnet
    volumes:
      - 'dbdata:/var/lib/mysql'
networks:
  appnet:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
  cachedata:
    driver: local
```

Question:

- How can I make them be able to talk to one another via API call? (On my local for development and for prod environment)
- On production, the setting will be a bit different, they will be in different machines but still in the same VPC or even through public network. What is the setting for that?

Note:

- I have been looking at `link` but apparently it is deprecated for `v3` or not really recommended
- Tried `curl` from project1 container to project2 container, by doing:

```
root@bc3afb31a5f1:/var/www/html# curl localhost:8050/login
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8050: Connection refused
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing them by their name as a hostname? So, for example, `app` would access `db` by using hostname `db` and port `3306`.

Comment: @ahwayakchih, I would like `app1` to be able to call to `app2` via api call, the `app1` can connect to their own `db` accordingly without any issue.

Comment: maybe something there will help https://stackoverflow.com/q/38088279/6352710

Comment: especially this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48024244/6352710

Comment: @ahwayakchih, it does not work: `Network test_network declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the network manually using `docker network create test_network` and try again.`

Comment: I guess it depends on the order of launching of instances. But in the question i linked to, there are other, older answers, that people seem to confirm as working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your final setup will be that each service will be running on a physically different system, there aren't really any choices.  One system can't directly access the Docker network on another system; the only way service 1 will be able to reach service 2 is via its host's DNS name (or IP address) and the published port.  Since this will be different in different environments, I'd suggest making that value a configured environment variable.

```yaml
environment:
  SERVICE_2_URL: 'http://service-2-host.example.com/' # default port 80
```

Once you've settled on that, you can use the same setup for a single-host deployment, mostly.  If your developer systems use Docker for Mac or Docker for Windows you should be able to use a [special Docker hostname](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds) to reach the other service

```yaml
environment:
  SERVICE_2_URL: 'http://host.docker.internal:8082/'
```

(If you use Linux on the desktop you will have to know some IP address for the host; not `localhost` because that means "this container", and not the `docker0` interface address because that will be on a specific network, but something like the host's `eth0` address.)

Your other option is to "borrow" the other Docker Compose network as an external network.  There is some trickiness if all of your Docker Compose setups have the same names; from some experimentation it seems like the Docker-internal DNS will always resolve to your own Docker Compose file first, and you have to know something like the Compose-assigned container name (which isn't hard to reconstruct and is stable) to reach the other service.

```yaml
version: '3'
networks:
  app2:
    external:
      name: app2_appnet
services:
  app:
    networks:
      - appnet
      - app2_appnet
    environment:
      SERVICE_2_URL: 'http://app2_app_1/' # using the service-internal port
      MYSQL_HOST: db # in this docker-compose.yml
```

(I would suggest using the [Docker Compose `default` network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) over declaring your own; that will mostly let you delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the file without any ill effect, but in this specific case you will need to declare `networks: [default, app2_default]` to connect to both.)

You may also consider a multi-host container solution when you're starting to look at this.  Kubernetes is kind of heavy-weight, but it will run containers on any node in the cluster (you don't specifically have to worry about placement) and it provides both namespaces and automatic DNS resolution for you; you can just set `SERVICE_2_URL: 'http://app.app2/'` to point at the other namespace without worrying about these networking details.

Comment: `http://host.docker.internal:{port}` solved my problem for local, and yes for production I will have to change it to the public IP of the servers. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you run this docker compose locally; given app and db are on the same network - appnet - *app* should be able to talk to *db* using localhost:${DB_PORT}.

In production, if app and db are on different machines; app would probably need to talk to database using ip or domain name.

Comment: I am not talking about `app` to `db`. But `app1` to `app2` which is in the same machine for development and it will be on a different machine for the production

Comment: @rfpdl have you tried `curl app2:80/login` from `app1` container? Because you seem to be setting it to listen on port `80`.

Comment: @ahwayakchih, tried just now, `root@bc3afb31a5f1:/var/www/html# curl cms_app_1:80/login
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: cms_app_1`

Comment: do app1 and app2 both share the appnet network? If so, you should be able to use localhost, if not, but they're on the same docker instance, you can use the container name i.e. app2:{port} - as per @ahwayakchih above

Comment: @rfpdl yeah, sorry, i only now noticed you want to connect form one docker-composed to another docker-composed project. Not from one of the instances to another inside the same composed project. Never tried that before :).

Comment: @ahwayakchih, no problem man. Thank you for taking time to help.

Comment: Still ok - if app1 and app2 containers are in same docker instance, but have different networks, you can connect using the container name.

Comment: @Ryan.Bartsch, they are not in the same docker instance, they have different docker-compose as they are in different folders.

Comment: If containers share same docker instance and same docker network, they can communicate over localhost (using published or exposed ports). Same docker instance, but different docker network, they can use container name (with published or exposed ports). If they're in different docker instances (i.e. different VMs), you'll need to use ip/dns (with published ports)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using different machines for the different docker deployments you good put them behind a regular webserver (Apache2, Nginx) and then route the traffic from the specific domain to `$APP_PORT` using a simple vhost. I prefer to do that instead of directly exposing the container to the network. This way you would also be able to host multiple applications on the same machine ( *if you like to* ). So I suggest you should not try to connect docker networks but "*regular* " ones.

Comment: For now, I just need my local to work, where I can have both app do API with one another. I am still clueless on the setup for Docker on this.

I do not understand what you are trying to point out though.

Answer (score 0):

Was playing around with inspect and cURL. I think I found the solution.

Locally:

- In my local, I inspected the container and view the `NetworkSettings.Network.<network name>.Gateway` which is `172.25.0.1`
- Then I get the the exposed port which is `8050`
- Then I did a curl inside the app1 container `curl 172.25.0.1:8050/login` to check whether `app1` can do a http request to app2 container. OR `docker exec -it project1_app_1 curl 172.25.0.1:8050/login`
- Vice versa, I did `curl 172.25.0.1:80` for `app2 -> app 1` OR `docker exec -it project2_app_1 curl 172.25.0.1:80`

The only issue is that, the `Gateway` value changes when we restart via `docker-compose up -d`

Production likewise:

I am not that pro with networking and stuff. My estimate for production would be:

Do `curl app2-domain.com` which is pointed to the app by the webserver as they are in their own machine (even with a load balancer).