# Laravel Docker - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

In my container when I run *php artisan migrate* I keep getting this error

```
In Connector.php line 67:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known


In Connector.php line 67:

  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Here's my .ENV file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:etukbJpSLgbRsdf5uOEGtLT5Qw+XB6y06Q38HPr
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=


BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

I tried to change DB_HOST to mysql but still same result as well as changed it to mariadb

Here's my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:

 # The Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ../.:/var/www
      - ./custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

 # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ../.:/var/www
      - ./vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8082:80

  # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

I searched for solution online but none of them helped. Does anyone have a suggestion as to why I keep getting that error?

Comment: Why did you write `DB_HOST=localhost` when using a seperate container?

Answer (score 17):

You should add a container_name to your database service

```
database:
image: mysql:5.7
container_name: database
```

And reference that name inside your .env MYSQL_HOST as:

```
MYSQL_CONNECTION=mysql
MYSQL_HOST=database
MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

rather than using localhost

you should also connect the database service and app using a network

add a networks block to the end of the docker-compose

```
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

and add this block to the end of your database serice and app servce

```
demo_db:
   .
   .
   .    
   networks:
      - app-network
  app:
   .
   .
   .
   networks:
      - app-network
```

here is a working demo for dockerizing a simple laravel app

https://bitbucket.org/RamiAmro/hello-laravel-docker/

Comment: You need neither `container_name:` nor a network other than the Compose-provided `default:` for inter-container communications to work.  In the `docker-compose.yml` file from the original question, `database` should be usable as a DNS name without any modifications.

Comment: Correct, they are all on default network if network not specified

Comment: perfect. thanks @rami worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by `DB_HOST=0.0.0.0` in ENV file, because Docker works on that port. The other solution is in terminal open docker container  `docker exec -it mydockername /bin/bash`  and in this bash execute `php artisan migrate`.

Answer (score 2):

It happens when the laravel application running in docker is not able to connect to database. I hope this could be helpful for those who have gone through the solution and not yet succeeded. I had similar problem and tried to change the DB_HOST localhost to 127.0.0.1  also with the name of the container/db host (as mentioned in docker-compose), yet I could not get this error resolved. So I updated my .env file like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
DB_PORT=3308 or any other port
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=your_user_name
DB_PASSWORD=your_password
```

which started working. I am not assuring it works 100% but you could give a try for this in case other option are not working.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to mysql as an external docker container, make sure that you implemented this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/38089080/1770571

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I found out that it was visible in the sail log that there was a problem with recovering the InnoDB database

[image: InnoDB error message]

**!! CAUTIOUS (THIS WILL DELETE THE WHOLE DATABASE) !!**

As it was my development environment, I tried *deleting the existing volume*

`./vendor/bin/sail down -v`

And then bringing up a new container again

`./vendor/bin/sail up`

Answer (score 0):

There's now Laravel Sail for anyone still interested.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail

> Laravel Sail is a light-weight command-line interface for interacting
> with Laravel's default Docker development environment. Sail provides a
> great starting point for building a Laravel application using PHP,
> MySQL, and Redis without requiring prior Docker experience.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found in the doc that when using Sail you should run all commands using sail instead of php. for example "php artisan migrate" => "sail artisan migrate".

for more insight about this:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#executing-sail-commands

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to connect `Pest Plugin` for `PHPSTORM`  with `Laravel` on `Sail` and I had the same problem. The problem was that on the configuration of php interpreter there was default `DOCKER` network name `bridge` and my sail docker containers where using different name .

To show your docker networks you can do it with
`docker network ls`

After that change the `network mode` to the one docker is using for your environment in

`Settings => PHP => Edit Docker Container Settings`.

credits to [link](https://codingwisely.com/blog/pest-along-phpstorm-and-laravel-sail)