# 502 Bad Gateway while setting up Nginx for an ASP .NET WebApp in a Container Network

Tags: c#, docker, nginx

I recently followed [a guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to get started with ASP .NET and created a simple WebApp.

Then I discovered Docker and from now on I would like to Dockerize of all of my services.

My idea is to run one container with Nginx and one container with my ASP .NET Webapp to route and manage incoming traffic.

The containers themselves are running just fine. I can also access the WebApp through its exposed port but accessing it through Nginx with port `80` returns:

> 502 Bad Gateway.

I have read that this may be due to Nginx not knowing the WebApp container but I have checked that they are in the same network.

**docker logs nginx_container returns this when I call localhost:80:**

```
2020/01/14 13:48:18 [error] 6#6: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/", host: "localhost"
2020/01/14 13:48:18 [error] 6#6: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/", host: "localhost"
2020/01/14 13:48:18 [error] 6#6: *12 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://localhost/favicon.ico", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
172.21.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2020:13:48:18 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36"
```

I am guessing that it is some kind of configuration that I am getting wrong or do not understand properly. Most of the WebApp configuration was auto-generated by VS.

**WebApp Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4000
EXPOSE 4500

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RazorPagesMovie.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "RazorPagesMovie.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "RazorPagesMovie.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RazorPagesMovie.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RazorPagesMovie.dll"]
```

**Nginx Dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**Nginx configuration:**

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream web-api {
        server razorpagesmovie:4000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://172.21.0.1:4000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

**Docker-Compose:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  reverseproxy:
    build:
      context: ./Nginx
      dockerfile: Nginx.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always

  razorpagesmovie:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}razorpagesmovie
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - reverseproxy
    restart: always
```

**Docker-Compose-Override:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  razorpagesmovie:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:4000;http://+:4500
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
      - "4500:4500"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

Comment: What network are they on? The default bridge network or did you create a custom internal one? I have a similar setup `E->Host:Port->Docker Nginx->Container` I created an internal network for them all to reside on. I also use the container name instead of docker IPs.

Comment: The name was auto-generated from the docker-compose call I suppose and it runs on the normal bridge driver. I did not create a custom network yet. What would internal mean here?

Comment: I made a new one called "internal" and assigned it to every container. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects). You need to make sure the two composes are on the same network and not new auto-generated ones else they HAVE to communicate through the host.

Comment: I was hesitant to test it at first because I have already confirmed that my containers are in the same network on the bridge driver. As a commenter in your link pointed out: the docker-compose file creates a default network. Well, I tested it anyway and now it works -  so this actually appears to be the solution. I will have to conduct more tests though to be sure and append it to my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects)

Comment: After more tests I realized that this was not the solution. It just magically worked after a restart. I have no explanation for this. I removed, recreated and restarted the containers and VS multiple times without success today. I have tested this without defining a network and it works just as well. Maybe I will not find out why this happened and could not be fixed without a shutdown but it works for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by editing the **Nginx configuration**. As I suspected there was some problem with it. After thoroughly reading the docs on Nginx again I think I understand how it works now.

**The updated Nginx configuration:**

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream rzpage {
        server razorpagesmovie:4000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name rzpage;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://razorpagesmovie:4000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

I am unsure if I should edit my answer into my question, so I will leave it as is for now.

Comment: Can you explain more? I compared your files and I don't get why the new config works!

Comment: My issue is over one year old and we moved on from Docker and Nginx to IIS/Windows Service hosting (as we don't need Linux support for now). I am afraid I cannot really help you with this as I don't remember any details about the problem at hand. I can only tell you that it worked at the end with the configuration shown. The most important part were the server-names. They had to line up with the names of the Docker containers if I remember correctly. Also, as I noted, restarting systems did often help, so if you run into an issue, restarting the containers or system may help.

Comment: Which file should this be added to ?

Comment: What do you mean? The posted solution is the nginx configuration file.