# docker-compose configuration to reach container from different project/network via domain url

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is a **hard** one but it would be great to solve it and my configuration would awesome!

I have two docker-compose projects: no 1. contains configuration for `traefik`, no 2. contains `my-service` that has `http://my-domain.tld` as parameter.

The goal is to call (let's say ping) `http://my-domain.tld` from `my-service` and get through to `traefik`. Both services now are in the same network but I need somehow to pass configuration that `http://my-domain.tld` points to `traefik`.

```yaml
# Project no 1. configuration for traefik that I want to access from no 2. project
version: '3.7'
services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    networks:
      - default
networks:
  default:
    name: traefik
```

```yaml
# Project no 2.
version: '3.7'
services:
  my-service:
    environment:
      - URL=http://my-domain.tld
    networks:
      - traefik
networks:
  traefik:
    external:
      name: traefik
```

### Tried solutions:

#### Variant a)

Does not work. When I call `http://my-domain.tld` it is directed to first node in `traefik` network (in my case it was `my-service` itself). Difference from original: `aliases` in network section.

```yaml
# Project no 2.
version: '3.7'
services:
  my-service:
    environment:
      - URL=http://my-domain.tld
    networks:
      traefik:
        aliases:
          - ${MERCURE_DOMAIN}
networks:
  traefik:
    external:
      name: traefik
```

#### Variant b)

Fails because `traefik` that service depends on is not in the project/network: `Service 'my-service' depends on service 'traefik' which is undefined.` Differences from original: `depends_on` and `extra_hosts`.

```yaml
# Project no 2.
version: '3.7'
services:
  my-service:
    environment:
      - URL=http://my-domain.tld
    networks:
      - traefik
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    extra_hosts:
      - http://my-domain.tld:traefik
networks:
  traefik:
    external:
      name: traefik
```

#### Variant c)

Works! However keep in mind that I had to hardcode IP address of `traefik` service. This is not the worst scenario but it makes project less portable and I want to avoid it. Differences from original: network configuration for no 1. project, static ip for `traefik` service and `extra_hosts` for no 2. project.

```yaml
# Project no 1. configuration for traefik that I want to access from next project
version: '3.7'
services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.133.239.10
networks:
  default:
    name: traefik
    driver: bridge
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: 172.133.239.0/24
```

```yaml
# Project no 2.
version: '3.7'
services:
  my-service:
    environment:
      - URL=http://my-domain.tld
    networks:
      - traefik
    extra_hosts:
          - http://my-domain.tld:172.133.239.10
networks:
  traefik:
    external:
      name: traefik
```

#### Variant d)

Is waiting for your suggestion how to make this perfect!

EDIT: rewrote docker-compose configuration to separate cases to show what I have tried and accomplished because there were some confusion about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38089080/4778343)

Comment: Nope. This different because I am not calling container name directly, I am calling http://my-domain.tld.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the hostname (or container name) of  `my-service` will be static you can just call it via it's hostname (or container name if no hostname was specified; it'll default to using it's container name as it's hostname).

i.e. if `my-service` has the hostname `container1` you can ping it like this from inside your other container, (as long as they're in the same Docker network): `ping container1`

Comment: But the main goal of mine is to call `http://my-domain.tld.` not `my-service`. `extra_hosts` let's me define this domain-to-host relation but only in the same network when `depends_on` is provided. I need to make this work on different networks.

Comment: @aurelijus what if you remove the depends_on? Also, i don't think you need that first networks: when using try 1, you'd be defining it twice.

Comment: @scott check out updated question. Tried to make it as clear as possible with all solutions I have tried.