# Cannot connect Wordpress on external dbgetaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, docker

I would like to run my `Wordpress` site on `Docker`, and I want to connect the `Wordpress` database to another container which have only the databases of all my sites.

For doing so, I've created a `LAMP` container using the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web: 
    image: webdevops/php-apache:alpine-php7
    ports:
      - "4500:80"
    volumes: 
      - ./www:/app
      - ./uploads.ini:/opt/docker/etc/php/php.ini

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
```

as you can see I've installed `Apache` as service using the `webdevops` image, this return the following:

[image]

Then, I've created a new container which have the `Wordpress` instance:

```
version: '3'

    services:
      wordpress:
       depends_on:
         - db
       image: wordpress:latest
       volumes:
         - ./wp/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
       ports:
         - "8000:80"
       restart: always
       environment:
         WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: lamp_db_1:3306
         WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
         WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: root
    
    volumes:
      dbdata:
      wp-content:
```

as you can see I mount the `wp-content` folder since I already have a Wordpress installation with plugins and media... then I tried to connect this container to `lamp_db_1` container but when I run this using:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

I get:

> MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

what I did wrong?

How can I connect the wordpress container to the `LAMP` container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a [custom network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) in your `LAMP` stack and have your `Wordpress` stack and other containers defined in other Compose files use this network by using `network.external` parameter in Compose.

Being on the same network, you'll be able to join your `lamp_db` container [using it's container name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) as hostname.

---

A complete example:

`docker-compose.yml` for `LAMP` stack:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  db:
    # This will be the hostname for your DB container on the network
    container_name: lamp_db
    image: mysql
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    # Have db container join our db network
    networks:
    - db_network

# Ensure our custom network is managed by this stack
networks:
  db_network:
    name: db_network
```

`docker-compose.yml` for `Wordpress` stack:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
    - "8000:80"
    environment:
      # Name of the db container
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: lamp_db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: root
    # Have wordpress container join our db network
    networks:
    - db_network

# Declare db_network as external with it's name
# Network won't be created by this stack but must exists before running
# See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1
networks:
  db_network:
    external: true
    name: db_network
```

And a generic example any service that would need to use our database:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  some_container:
    image: some-image:latest
    # Have this container join our db network
    networks:
    - db_network
    # Note: make sure to reference db container by it's hostname lamp_db

networks:
  db_network:
    external: true
    name: db_network
```

Notes:

- `db_network` is managed via `LAMP` stack. When `up`ing the `LAMP` stack, Docker Compose will ensure this network is created. Other stacks using this network should declare it as [`external: true`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1) with it's name
- You'll need `version: '3.5'` or more to be able to use `network.name` config

Answer (score 1):

It seems the reason you are running into this issue is due to the fact that you have two separate services.   One contains your LAMP stack and the other contains your wordpress image.

When you run docker-compose it sets up a [single network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for your app.  Thus your wordpress image isn't on the same network as your LAMP stack.

You can add your wordpress container to your LAMP docker-compose.yml file such as

```
version: "3"

services:
  web: 
    image: webdevops/php-apache:alpine-php7
    ports:
      - "4500:80"
    volumes: 
      - ./www:/app
      - ./uploads.ini:/opt/docker/etc/php/php.ini

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8088:80"

  wordpress:
   depends_on:
     - db
   image: wordpress:latest
   volumes:
     - ./wp/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
   ports:
     - "8000:80"
   restart: always
   environment:
     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
     WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
     WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: root
    
volumes:
  dbdata:
  wp-content:
```

And unless you are doing something specific with your php-apache image you can actually remove it at this point.

Another approach you could take if you do not want everything in the same docker-compose file is that you can manually define the networks and get your containers to join them.  The answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects) show how to do that fairly easily.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I understood that I've two different networks, but what about if I have multiple wordpress instances? Should I attach them in the same `docker-compose.yml`? It's a good practice?

Comment: That really all depends on if you would consider them one application.   Docker-compose provides a way of basically grouping together several containers as a single application (ex. Wordpress, database, and phpmyadmin).  I personally would ensure each wordpress instance had its own database and if the db is going to be in a container then a docker-compose file containing two containers (db and wordpress) for each site.