# Connect to multiple pre-existing external networks in docker

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have two different pre-existing networks created by two separated docker-compose operations. The first one is Kafka and the second one is MySQL DB. The third container is a Kafka consumer, which has to have access to the DB and Kafka topic. So I expect to connect them in another docker-compose something like this so I could use services like "db" or "broker" defined somewhere external:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER: broker:29092
      DB_MYSQL_USER: ${DB_MYSQL_REMOTE_USER}
      DB_MYSQL_PASS: ${DB_MYSQL_PASS}
      DB_MYSQL_ADDRESS: db:3306
      KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME: ${KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME}
      KAFKA_GROUP_NAME: ${KAFKA_GROUP_NAME}

networks:
  db_container_default:
    external: true
  kafka_client_default:
    external: true
```

Eventually, the container doesn't recognize these networks at all.

The only way to properly connect to ONLY ONE network is [here](https://runnable.com/docker/docker-compose-networking).
So I ended up with settings like this, which is utter lame(connect to the exposed port of the DB by host-ip):

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER: broker:29092
      DB_MYSQL_USER: ${DB_MYSQL_REMOTE_USER}
      DB_MYSQL_PASS: ${DB_MYSQL_PASS}
      DB_MYSQL_ADDRESS: 192.168.1.103:3307
      KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME: ${KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME}
      KAFKA_GROUP_NAME: ${KAFKA_GROUP_NAME}

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: kafka_client_default
```

How should I properly configure my third docker-compose?

Comment: Like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects. Maybe you can chain all three of them. i.e put all of them in the same network. That way each container can access each others by service name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually declare that the containers should be attached to the networks.

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    # Each service needs to declare what networks it attaches to
    # The default is to only attach to "default"
    # If anything is explicitly listed then "default" is not used
    networks:
      - db_container_default
      - kafka_client_default

# You also need to declare at the top level that the networks exist
networks:
  db_container_default:
    external: true
  kafka_client_default:
    external: true
```

You might be able to simplify this by having fewer Compose files (for example, declare the application's database in the same `docker-compose.yml` as the application itself), or by configuring all of the parts to have the same `default` network.