# Http request between two docker networks

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, guzzle

I'm using two different docker-compose setup for two different projects. I need to make an HTTP request from one to other and tried to send it like `http://localhost:8050/api` but keep getting cURL error even though it is working on Postman. Here are the docker-compose files:

**File 1 (Request receiver)**

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: core
    build: .cloud/php
    image: app-core
    ports:
      - "9050:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www:cached
    networks:
      - core_network

  nginx:
    container_name: core.nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8050:8000"
    volumes:
      - .cloud/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:cached
      - ./:/var/www:cached
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - core_network

  pgres:
    container_name: core.postgres
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "54321:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: sampleuser
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - .cloud/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - core_network
networks:
  core_network:
    driver: bridge
```

**File 2 (Request sender)**

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: b2c
    build: .cloud/php
    image: app-b2c
    ports:
      - "9055:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www:cached
    networks:
      - b2c_network

  nginx:
    container_name: b2c.nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8055:8000"
    volumes:
      - .cloud/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:cached
      - ./:/var/www:cached
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - b2c_network 
networks:
  b2c_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: I did some more searching and best solution I came across is described in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects as it suggest; these two compose files must be in the same network in order to communicate.

Comment: Couldn't make it work. All I can do is to grab the container assigned gateway id with `docker inspect <container_name>`and use it on the http request as the host.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone struggling you can make requests like: `http://host.docker.internal:8050`