# Connect to from one container to another container from diffrent docker-compose

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

my first docker-compose looks like

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: php-fpm
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    env_file:
      - .env
```

and my second docker-compose looks like this:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: web
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

And now I would like to `curl` from `php-fpm` container to `web` container. So I am exectuing this command:

```
docker-compose exec php-fpm curl http://web:80/
```

I am getting error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: web
```

When I go to the browser on the host and type address `http://localhost:8080` I can see the response from `web` container.

To summarize: my question is: How to curl from `php-fpm` container to `web` container?

PS. In a real project, these docker-compose files look much more complicated and I cannot merge them into one docker-compose file.

Answer (score 1):

See

- [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects)
- https://docs.docker.com/network/

You should configure both the containers on the same network

Comment: Could you add a short example of the proposed solution so this is not a link-only answer?