# Docker. Communication between Laravel containers

Tags: laravel, docker, api, guzzle

I have a project that I am trying to develop with a microservices approach. I prepared the APIs on two separate microservices and completed their tests. When I send a request from container A to container B, I get the error ***cURL error 7: Could not connect to localhost port 8100: Connection refused***. After my research, I couldn't find a solution.
Request Architecture:
I'm trying to make a request from 127.0.0.1:8000 to an api address running at 127.0.0.1:8100.

What should I do to fix this problem? My question may be wrong, so I apologize in advance.

thanks

My Compose File First Container

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
      build:
          context: ./docker/8.0
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
          args:
              WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
      image: sail-8.0/app
      container_name: MP-Main-Service-Laravel
      extra_hosts:
          - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
      ports:
          - 8000:8000
      environment:
          WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
          LARAVEL_SAIL: 2
          XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
          XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
      volumes:
          - '.:/var/www/html'
      networks:
          - sail
      depends_on:
          - mysql
          - redis
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        container_name: MP-Main-Service-MySql
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - "/var/lib/mysql"
        networks:
            - sail
    phpmyadmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
        container_name: MP-Main-Service-PhpMyAdmin
        ports:
            - 8081:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            MYSQL_ROOT_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        networks:
            - sail
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        container_name: MP-Main-Service-Redis
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

My Compose File Second Container

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        container_name: MP-Communication-Service-Laravel
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - 8100:8000
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        container_name: MP-Communication-Service-MySql
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-33061}:33061'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - "/var/lib/mysql"
        networks:
            - sail
    phpmyadmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
        container_name: MP-Communication-Service-PhpMyAdmin
        ports:
            - 8082:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            MYSQL_ROOT_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        networks:
            - sail
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        container_name: MP-Communication-Service-Redis
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-63791}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

Comment: "*I'm trying to make a request from 127.0.0.1:8000 to an api address running at 12.0.0.1:8100.*" - What exactly do you mean by this? With a http-request, we do not define the source address explicitly, it is read from the TCP headers.

Comment: I don't see the service that is running on port 8100 here. If you have it on a separate docker compose file then it probably is using a different network. Maybe try putting both services in the same .yml

Comment: @apokryfos I have attached both compose files. I'm new to Docker. The things I've done wrong may be stupid. I'm sorry

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects it seems all you have to do is in one of the two .yml files replace `driver: bridge` with `external: true` then both services will join the same bridged network. However I would be wary of port conflicts here since you are replicating services. Maybe a better idea is to find out a way to give a known hostname to each container so they can communicate via that instead of "localhost" (not idea how to do this though)

Comment: To communicate between docker containers you don’t have to use 127.0.0.1 address, they each have its own IP/name.

Comment: I solved the problem simply. Maybe this answer will help others. My solution was: In addition to the ip address of my computer on the modem, I also accessed the container port addresses on docker. This was the solution for me too. I reached the address **127.0.0.1:8000** that I mentioned in the question with **192.168.1.x:8000**.

Answer (score 0):

Notice: this solution is raw and for development time:

First get container gateway ip:

```
❯ docker inspect {container id} | grep -i Gateway
```

Second Suppose it gives you `172.25.0.1`

Your url pattern will look like this:

```
http://{containerIp}:{port}/...
```

or:

```
http://172.25.0.1:8585/...
```

The port is the same as the one you put in your `docker-compose.yaml` file.