# Build the EFK system used for simulating logging server on Docker

Tags: docker, fluentd, efk, fluent-docker

I want to simulate laravel logging to EFK system server 
Base on this, I build up two container. One of laravel project's container. The ohter is EFK system container

[image: flow-chart]

but EFK's fluentd does not catch any data or event

---

my container's compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8010:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:delegated
      - ./server:/var/www/:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
      - fluentd
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-address: fluentd:24225
        fluentd-async-connect: 'true'
        fluentd-retry-wait: '1s'
        fluentd-max-retries: '30'
        tag: fubo.logger

  php:
    container_name: php-laravel
    build: ./php
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www/:delegated

  db:
    build: ./mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data/:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - 8811:80
    depends_on:
      - db

  fluentd:
    build: ./fluentd
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/conf:/fluentd/etc
    ports:
      - "24225:24224"
      - "24225:24224/udp"
    networks:
      - docker-efk_efk_network
networks:
  docker-efk_efk_network:
    external: true
```

my container's fluent.conf:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /etc/logs/laravel.log
  pos_file /etc/logs/laravel.log.pos
  tag docker.space
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</source>

<match *.**>
  @type forward
  send_timeout 60s
  recover_wait 10s
  hard_timeout 60s

  <server>
    name dockerSpace
    host docker-efk-fluentd-1
    port 24224
    weight 60
  </server>
</match>
```

---

EFK's container compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.15.1
    container_name: kibana
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - I18N_LOCALE=zh-tw
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    links:
      - elasticsearch

  fluentd:
    build: ./fluentd
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/conf/:/fluentd/etc/
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
      - "24224:24224/udp"
    networks:
      - efk_network
networks:
  efk_network:
    driver: bridge
```

EFK's container fluent.conf:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24225
  bind docker-space_fluentd_1
</source>

<match *.**>
  @type copy

  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearch
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix fluentd
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    include_tag_key true
    type_name access_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```

This is my container networks list:

| name | driver | scope |
| --- | --- | --- |
| docker-efk_default | bridge | local |
| docker-efk_efk_network | bridge | local |
| docker-space_default | bridge | local |

What's wrong my understanding?

Comment: Please add your `docker-compose` commands as well. Looks like the terms are a bit incorrect. A pod contains multiple containers. The services in docker-compose YAML files correspond to different containers. The fluentd running in the same pod alongside the app is referred to as a sidecar pattern. From the connectivity side, all these services should be able to communicate on the same network as configured in the above configs i.e. `localhost`.

Comment: Also, please add the output of `kubectl get pods`. Add `--namespace <ns>` accordingly if the deployment is not in the `default` namespace.

Comment: Are you getting an error from the first ("my") fluentd?  My suspicion is, since the two fluentds are in separate Compose files, they're on separate Docker networks, and the `test-efk` hostname doesn't resolve.  See also [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects).

Comment: I update my docker-compose.yml and fluent.conf 
Now, I get the new error "error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ForwardOutput::NoNodesAvailable error="no nodes are available".

Comment: this is kind error like didn't assign the correct host or port?

Comment: @HenryKao: Looks like the `links` option has been deprecated in favor of `networks`. See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links and https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#networks.

Comment: @Azeem It's work. I change some fluentd configure. Thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two step to do:

First, ensurce both of container has connected each other. More detail can see this.
[How to link multiple docker-compose services via network](https://tjtelan.com/blog/how-to-link-multiple-docker-compose-via-network/)

Second, modify EFK container's fluentd configuare:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 24224
</source>

<match *.**>
  @type copy

  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearch
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix fluentd
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    include_tag_key true
    type_name access_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```

And ... it's work.
[image]