# Hashicorp Vault - Django query from docker container

Tags: django, docker, hashicorp-vault, vault

Good afternoon,

I have a two docker containers, one running a django app and the other running Hashicorp Vault as I am starting to play with Vault in a dev environment.

I am using HVAC from a django view to write a secret to the vault that is entered by a user to set up an integration to a REST API for a data pull.

When I run the following from my host machine, it writes just fine.

```
client_write = hvac.Client(url='http://127.0.0.1:8200', token='MY_TOKEN')
client_write.is_authenticated()
```

When I run the same from the Django container, it fails with:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8200): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /v1/auth/token/lookup-self (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7f2a21990610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
> Connection refused'))

Django docker container is running on localhost:8000 & the vault is localhost:8200.  I also have a front end written in VueJS running on localhost:8080 that has no trouble communicating back and forth with the django rest API (django-rest-framework).

Is there something in vault that I need to list where the queries can come from?

EDIT: Also, I have used both my purpose built tokens with policies that allow writing of the secrets in question along with the following perms input (per https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/781 ):

```
path "auth/token/lookup-self" {
    capabilities = ["read"]
} 

path "auth/token/renew-self" {
    capabilities = ["update"]
}
```

Furthermore, the same behavior occurs when testing with the root token and the purpose built tokens work from the host system.

Vault Config:

```
{
  "listener":  {
    "tcp":  {
      "address":  "0.0.0.0:8200",
      "tls_disable":  "true"
    }
  },
  "backend": {
    "file": {
      "path": "/vault/file"
    }
  },
  "default_lease_ttl": "240h",
  "max_lease_ttl": "720h",
  "ui": true,
  "api_addr": "http://0.0.0.0:8200",
}
```

Thank you, I am very new to Vault and am struggling through it a bit.

BCBB

Comment: `localhost` in the Django container and `localhost` in the Vault container are two different `localhost`s, which are both different from `localhost` outside a container.  See _e.g._ [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for setup to communicate between two containers.

Comment: Thanks for your help. They are all apart of the default network. If I try to use the specific docker networking IP from docker inspect, it just times out. If they are a part of the default network, shouldn't they be able to communicate?  My Django can talk back to my Postgres container (though they are defined in the same docker-compose...) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I neglected to provide enough relevant information in my first post due to my not understanding.  Thanks to the reference to networking in compose in the comment above, I started down a path.

I realize now that I have each element in a different docker-compose: project_ui/docker-compose for the VueJS front end, project_api/ for the Django & Postgres, and then project_vault for the hashicorp vault container.

To enable these to talk, I followed the guidance here: [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects)

I created a network in the django app, and then linked the other containers to it as described in that answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and was able to resolve it by making two changes in my configurations.
1st - In my vault configuration I had to change my listener config to 0.0.0.0

```
listener "tcp" {
  address     = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = "true"
}
```

2nd - In my django settings I had to use the container name in the URL

```
VAULT_URL = 'http://vault:8200'
```