# Connect to Mysql database from another docker application

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, docker

I have 2 Laravel applications running in docker environment.

The first application `docker-compose` file (which called `mobile` app)

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
    laravel:

services:
    nginx:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockers/nginx/Dockerfile
        container_name: mobile-server-nginx
        ports:
            - "8188:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/
        depends_on:
            - php
            - mysql
        networks:
            - laravel
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0.28
        container_name: mobile-server-mysql
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "5306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        networks:
            - laravel
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockers/php/Dockerfile
        container_name: mobile-server-php
        extra_hosts: 
            - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/
        ports:
            - "9001:9000"
        networks:
            - laravel
        depends_on:
            - mysql
```

The second application `docker-compose` file: (which called `resident` app)

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
    resident:

services:
    nginx:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockers/nginx/Dockerfile
        container_name: resident-backend-nginx
        ports:
            - "8088:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/
        depends_on:
            - php
            - mysql
        networks:
            - resident
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        container_name: resident-backend-mysql
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "6306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        networks:
            - resident
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockers/php/Dockerfile
        container_name: resident-backend-php
        extra_hosts: 
            - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/
        ports:
            - "9002:9000"
        networks:
            - resident
        depends_on:
            - mysql
```

2 applications work separated perfectly. Now, in `mobile` application, I want to connect to `resident` application database to retrieve some data.
In the `mobile` application:

- In `config/database.php`, I added 1 more database connection:

```
        'resident_mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_RESIDENT_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_RESIDENT_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_RESIDENT_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_RESIDENT_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_RESIDENT_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_RESIDENT_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_RESIDENT_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

- Then, I set env variables in `.env` file:

```
DB_RESIDENT_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_RESIDENT_PORT=6306 // exposed mysql port in `resident_app`
DB_RESIDENT_DATABASE={database name}
DB_RESIDENT_USERNAME={database_user}
DB_RESIDENT_PASSWORD={database_password}
```

- Create an api to test in `api.php`:

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    $user = \DB::connection('resident_mysql')->select('select * from users');
    return $user;
});
```

- Finally, test api with postman, but it shows error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from users)`
  [image]

I've searched for this error but cannot find any answer.

#### UPDATE

- According from @David Maze, I've changed some config in `docker-compose` file in `mobile` app.
- In `docker-compose` file, add external network

```
networks:
    laravel:
        driver: bridge
    residentbackend_resident: // this is network in `resident` app, which type is `bridge`
        external: true
```

- Then add external network to `php` service in `networks` section:

```
        networks:
            - laravel
            - residentbackend_resident
```

- In `.env`, change `DATABASE_HOST` to mysql service name of `resident` app

```
DB_RESIDENT_HOST=mysql1
```

But it still return the same error as above.

Comment: Does the setup in [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects) help you?  As always in Docker, the special IPv4 address 127.0.0.1 means "this container" and it won't connect to one of the other containers, in either file.

Comment: (You could simplify this setup without affecting its functionality by removing unnecessary options like `tty:`, `container_name:`, and `networks:`; you likely do not need the `extra_hosts:` block either.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, Thank for your answer, I've tried to set up a external network (I've updated on my post) like your reference link but it still doesn't work. Can you check if I have any mistake in my config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider here.

First, each container is a separate node in a bigger network.
So setting `DB_RESIDENT_HOST=127.0.0.1` will not work, as it does not reference your local machine, but the (PHP) container itself.

Second, each `docker-compose.yml` creates a separate network, where all the containers defined are attached too. They can only communicate with each other and the host.
You need to attach an external network to the containers, that should be able to communicate across the stacks. But that, it seems like, you have already done by now.

Third, you used the port `6306`, which is the exposed port on your local machine. Internally, the container still uses the port `3306`. And as those containers communicate now directly (through the external docker network), this is the port to use.

And another thing I noticed is, that those containers have the same names across each stack (compose definitions, not container names). When accessing the `mysql` container, it probably routes to the container in the same file.
Maybe the `hostname` keyword solves this, but I haven't used that.
What definitely works, is either renaming them or setting the config to the internal IP address of the container itself.
Run `docker inspect resident_mysql` (replace the name with the correct one), search for "NetworkSettings", then "Networks", find the external network, that is attached to both containers, and use the value in "IPAddress".

Comment: What a simple solution! Also, when looking for solution, I found another solution worked too. I changed host and port in `.env` to `DB_RESIDENT_HOST=host.docker.internal` & `DB_RESIDENT_PORT=6306` (`6306` is the mysql port of `resident` app)

Answer (score 0):

DB host cannot be 127.0.0.1, Since it is a separate docker container you have to add the mysql docker private IP or the name

DB_RESIDENT_HOST=mysql

[example for your reference](https://github.com/shamith234/Laraval-php8)