# Docker: connection to the database in a different container

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I have two containers: for **main website** and for **forum**. Both have their **own databases**. But I need to fetch some information within forum (Laravel) from website-database.

I tried everything in my .env: **SECOND_DB_HOST=**

- 172.20.0.2 (website docker container ip adress)
- localhost
- 127.0.0.1
- site-db (website docker container name)

**SECOND_DB_PORT=** should be **3306** in any case, I suppose?

Every time I get "connection refused". Within the website-container the first database works great.

Do I need to some sort of bridge or how is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Use docker-compose - and you can connect by service name

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] that shows the setup (not a screen shot of a management application but actual source code)?  You normally would not directly try to access another service's database, but instead make an API call to the other service itself, but if the two services are set up separately you'll hit similar networking problems.

Comment: If your screen shot is of Docker Desktop's representation of Compose projects, are you trying to set up [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects)?

Answer (score 1):

So I successfully tried bridges and it works!

```
docker network create my-network
```

and then all 4 containers into new network..

```
docker network connect my-network CONTAINER_ID
```

and then the first DB is accessible by it's name! :-)

Comment: docker-compose makes life a lot easier with these things