# Communication between multiple docker-compose version 3 projects

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

### My question is exactly [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects?rq=2), except [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48024244/10263994) works using docker-compose version '2' for the `client`, but not version '3'.

I have two docker-compose:

- One for my server, which consists of multiple microservices.
- One for my client, which also consists of multiple microservices.

I need a network to have them communicate, and to expose the port on the host machine for external clients to also be able to connect.

Here is a reproduction. I made a small repository to hold the minimal reproduction so you can clone and try it yourself: https://github.com/Yanis-F/reprod-dockercompose

## `server/`

### `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_server:
    build: .
    networks:
      - my_network
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

networks:
  my_network:
    external: true
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

`index.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

## `client/`

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_client:
    build: .
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
    external: true
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM curlimages/curl:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY script.sh .

CMD ["sh", "script.sh"]
```

`script.sh`:

```bash
msg=$(curl localhost:3000)

echo "Message: $msg"
```

---

First, I created the virtual network `my_network` with `docker network create my_network`.
Then After launching the server with `cd server/ && docker-compose up`, I want to launch the client.
When running `cd client/ && docker-compose up`, I get the error:

```
Creating client_my_client_1 ... done
Attaching to client_my_client_1
my_client_1  |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
my_client_1  |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
my_client_1  | curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
my_client_1  | Message:
client_my_client_1 exited with code 0
```

However, if I just run `cd client/ && sh script.sh`, it works and give me:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    13  100    13    0     0   1957      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2166
Message: Hello, World!
```

---

Why is my service `my_client` in the `client/docker-compose.yml` not able to reach for the service `my_server` in the `server/docker-compose.yml` despite them sharing the same virtual network `my_network` ?
The connection works if I launch the script `sh client/script.sh` from the host machine, how can I also get it to work from the docker container it runs in ?