# Integrate docker-compose of dependent application in another client application in CI

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a service `foo` which is, among other things, a client of service `bar`.

In my CI, testing works by deploying `bar`, so `foo` can connect to it.

To do that, I'm checking out `bar` repo and running its docker-compose file + running some other scripts to check if `bar` is ready to be used.

Is there a better way to do this ? I was thinking of packaging `bar` docker compose in an image which just needs to be pulled and integrated in `foo` docker compose.

Comment: How complex is the downstream service?  [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects) is a fairly well-trodden path, and if the other service incorporates things like a service-specific database then launching its preëxisting `docker-compose.yml` might be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: The approach you suggested is what we are doing currently. Service `bar` has several runtime deps (namely a postgres DB + migrations) in its docker compose and it's stored in a separate repo than `foo`.