# How can I create communication between compose files, that need to act independently

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two docker compose files, for example backend and monitoring. I need to create communication between them. It is possible using same network, and docs telling me to create network in one file and then use

```yaml
external: true
```

in another.
But I want possibility to run only *backend* or only *monitoring*. And of course I want them to communicate if they both are running.

I can create the network with

```bash
docker network create some_network
```

and then run one or another, or both of them but are there some better ways?

Comment: It sounds like you're aware of [Communication between multiple docker-compose projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects); what are you asking that's different from that question?  Some of the answers there suggest that, if both Compose files declare the same `networks: { default: { name: } }` then neither needs to be flagged "external"; does that work?

Comment: Then I have the warning message tells that something like one network has already been created, consider to use ```external: true```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

1. Create a network.
2. Assign both containers to it.
3. Use the container name/id as hostname to mutual reference them.

**Edit:**

Due your comment, I propose you the following scenario:

1. You have 3 yaml files: network creation, container A creation, container B creation.
2. Container A and B yaml files address the network defined in network creation yaml
3. Invoke docker compose by `docker-compose build -f network.yaml -f container-a.yaml -f container-b.yaml .` .

That's all!

Comment: So creating network by hand is the only way? I am aware, that developers will forget about it. I have the option of writing script ofc to start app with network creation, but I am looking for easier ways, if they exist.

Comment: By the YAML you can create a network in a simple way, don't warry: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ .

Comment: yeah, but the doc tells to create network in one of two compose files, I have not the two containers but two compose files.

Comment: In this case I edit the post for you.