# Docker containerized WebApp can not access Docker containerized WebApi

Tags: c#, docker

I have "containerized" both a C# (blazor) WebApp and Web Api as next:

- Web Api:

```
docker run -dt -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" --name weatherapicontainer -p32720:8080 weatherapi:dev
```

- Web App:

```
docker run -dt -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" --name weatherappcontainer -p32730:80 weatherapp:dev
```

This nicely give me next running containers (on my local machine running docker host):

```
PS C:\dockertest\Weather> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS             PORTS                               NAMES

2f30cce67706   weatherapp:dev   "dotnet Weather.Serv…"   8 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes       443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32730->80/tcp      weatherappcontainer

79a25087381f   weatherapi:dev   "dotnet Weather.Api.…"   2 hours ago     Up About an hour   8081/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32720->8080/tcp   weatherapicontainer
```

From within the Web App I setup a `httplient` to refer to the Api as next:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<WeatherForecastDataService>(client =>
{
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:32720/");
});
```

If I only run the Web Api in a container on my local machine and start the Web App from for example IIS then this works fine, but when I also run the Web App on a container then this fails (yes ... it doesn't recognize the localhost because I assume the container where the Web App run's has not notion of localhost ..., so I get next error in the Web App:

> blazor.server.js:1  [2024-02-05T11:42:50.405Z] Error: >System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address >(localhost:32720)

So my question: how must next be defined in the Web App so i can access the Web API running in the container on my local machine with portsettings ext/int : 32720:8080

```cs
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:32720/");
```

Thx for any response !

Emmanuel.

Comment: Localhost is local to the container itself, not the host machine it is run on.  So you need to use the host machines IP, DNS Name.

Comment: might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects - so with docker compose, the host would be simply the name of the service plus the internal IP (for server to server).

Comment: The two containers aren't in same network, You can create a [network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) and run them both in the same network.